# A moderator declined two of my NAA flags on the same post

Tags: support, not-an-answer, disputed-flags

**Real duplicate:** [What to do with answers in a different programming language than the one asked for?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/375424/5958455)

I saw [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47447867/5958455) a few days ago. The question was about looping in **C**, and the answer included a **wrong** code snippet **in Python**. At first glance I raised an NAA flag, which was declined by a mod. I searched on MSO and created a custom flag:

> The Q is asked in C++, but this answer is not only wrong, but also **in Python**(!!). I have an NAA flag declined already, so in regard to [this post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/290047/5958455) I'm flagging here.

It just got declined again.

[image: Screenshot]

The link in my flag claimed that an answer in the wrong language is not a valid answer, thus is NAA.

**Please**. The *language* refers to *programming language*, not *human language*! (i.e. Java/C, not English/Spanish), as referred to by the post in my flag.

Comment: From *"what not to flag"* part of the suggested dupe: *"Any post that attempts to answer the question—however badly—is **still an answer**! **Do not use the "not an answer" flag for wrong answers.** Moderators do not judge the technical correctness of answers.  You can **downvote** such answers as a signal that they are bad answers and not useful, but they are still answers, so you **should not flag them**."*

Comment: "wrong language" in this case refers to human language, not programming language.  Had the answer used c++, but the text written in Flemish, you would be correct that it's NAA.

Comment: @MichaelGaskill How did you jump to this?

Comment: There's a meta Stack Exchange discussion about it.  I don't have the opportunity to search for it, but I do recall reading it not long ago.

Comment: @MichaelGaskill If it were written in another human language (e.g. Spanish), it would have been removed quickly.

Comment: Not necessarily so.  I had flagged 2 questions at separate times as such, and these were subsequently translated by another user before the flag was handled by the moderator.

Comment: *an answer in the wrong language is not a valid answer* ... the post is English, how wrong can that be?

Comment: Dear me! It refers to programming language! See edit **and** the post my flag mentioned.

Comment: @iBug hey, although it is not Friday, you still need to bring your sense of humor, at least I did ....

Comment: @rene Because I've already been driven mad by people prior to you :(

Comment: @iBug oh, yeah, adding insult to injury is my core competence, I like to live up to expectations, you're welcome ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a number of possible reasons your follow-up flag was also declined:

- The moderator doesn't want you to even state that the answer is wrong because that's an almost automatic reason to decline a flag.
- The moderator feels that the answer attempts to answer the question despite the fact that the code is in a different language. Whether it gets it right or wrong is irrelevant, but the fact that you state that the answer is wrong means you probably considered it an attempt to answer, because if the answer were altogether irrelevant, one would say that it is irrelevant, not right or wrong.

  Note that this is a *very* liberal interpretation of events; most "wrong language" answers are code dumps that either are altogether off-topic, or at least they don't even try to make themselves relevant in which case yes, they should be deleted, because they're only serving as a distraction. This answer is different.
- The moderator was careless, and *did* mean to delete the answer after all.