# What to do with answers in a different programming language than the one asked for?

Tags: discussion, answers, deleted-answers, code-languages

I stumbled on an old, too broad Java question yesterday (no effort asking for an algorithm). Having quite some votes, views and answers, I decided to browse through them, and found three answers which were in a different language (Python, C/C++ and Haskell). After conferring with users in the SOCVR we decided to delete those, as the question was explicitly tagged [java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java) and answers in other languages would thus be technically incorrect.

Today, however, a moderator undeleted one of those answers. Does this mean that it's OK to post an answer in a different language than the one asked for?

---

PS: I'd rather not link the question due to the meta effect.

Comment: Strongly related: [If the question is specifically about a certain language, is an answer in another language valid?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/290046/7296893) and the dupe target on that one. Not marking as a duplicate because I think a mod undeleting such an answer is a new thing and should be discussed.

Comment: If it's asking for a generic algorithm then surely answers in other languages than the tagged one can be useful for future visitors, for whom we build this site?

Comment: @ivarni might be, but that does not change the fact that this question is too broad (so should not be answered in the first place) and that the OP put [tag:java] there himself. A more generic question would then needed to be asked in another question, or the OP must change their question to be generic, since we'd change the meaning of it by changing the language to [tag:language-agnostic] or something.

Comment: So, just out of curiosity here, you agreed with other users in chat to coordinate downvoting and then deletion with a set of answers because they were viewed as "technically inaccurate"? The duplicate is correct here, just vote next time. Moderators do not cast binding delete votes based on technical accuracy, and neither should a group of users in chat.

Comment: @Adriaan Absolutely, but you made it sound like you were deleting those answers because they were in a different language and not because the question was broad. Maybe just delete the question if that is the problem?  Or remove the java-tag? Why just delete answers of potential value?

Comment: @ivarni as stated I will not remove the java tag without cooperation from the OP as it would change their question. Yes, the question is too broad, but some of the answers do hold value, so I'd be fine with closing it and leaving as-is. Answers in non-Java would be noise here, however detailed and correct in their own language, because people would be looking for java solutions to the problem if they were to end up on that question. If they wanted a Python solution, they'd have searched for a question in Python instead.

Comment: It is a highly specific question about an algorithm, clear as a bell, the OP indicated his language preference.  Yet the chatroom decided to close it as too broad.  WTF?  Either you consider it an algorithm question and the answer is on topic.  Or you consider it a [java] question and it isn't too broad.  You can't do both.  Forcing moderators to disagree with each other is going to blow up sooner or later as well.  Consider to limit the collateral damage a bit by not piling on downvotes.  4 users already voted to re-open, done.

Comment: I would argue that a question tagged with [tag:java] is expected to have java answers. I didn't see anything in the question that suggested the java tag was wrong or unwarranted. By that fact Haskell and Python answers don't answer the question. As NAA flags will not work / are not meant for these cases I used my delete vote privilege to delete vote the answers. If those answers deemed valuable they can be reposted under a language specific question which offers lasting values for those looking for solution in that specific language.

Comment: @HansPassant the too broad close vote seems applicable here as beyond a problem description there is not much more to go on, aka lacking an attempt. Is your distaste for this closure caused by the fact that when asked these kind of question were kind of okay  or is your concern more how interesting the question (and answers) about this algorithm can be? In the latter case can you give us some guidelines/rule of thumbs how we can spot these algorithm questions clear as a bell so we can re-adjust?

Comment: @rene - I have a strong distaste for bored SO users that close a question because they don't understand the relevance or know the proper answer.  That is rarely a problem with users that moderate content based on them frequenting a tag, they know the subject.  It is a growing problem with the chatroom visitors.  Ultimately a discipline problem, I guess, no idea how you'd tackle that.  Just make sure the jackass that [caused this disaster](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/374437/how-to-handle-other-users-rude-behaviour-towards-new-users) to never be let back in.

Comment: In other words, Hans has a beef with a group of users doing their best to shape the site how they consider is best for Stack Overflow, without suggesting anything constructive.

Comment: The question was asking for an algorithm? That is language-agnostic. Usually an OP tags it with the language they are working with - whether that's Java, C#, Python, Basic, or what-have-you. From the way you describe it, the question should not have a language tag at all.

Comment: @Braiam: In other words, we're talking about a group of users doing their best to bypass consensus and just impose their will despite the fact it runs counter to consensus.  The "constructive" suggestion is that they need to take their proposed plan of action to Meta and respect the consensus decision.

Comment: @BenVoigt which consensus? What makes their voice less consensus-y than your group? If the 95% of the users doesn't care, 3% says delete and 2% say no, is that anywhere less valid?

Comment: @Braiam: Do they have hundreds of votes supporting their version of what "Not An Answer" means?  [The community consensus](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/225370/your-answer-is-in-another-castle-when-is-an-answer-not-an-answer) does.  And [again](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/265553/103167).  In fact, that users supporting a competing idea of NAA were not supporting that interpretation on meta but simply flagging left and right was already a problem which Shog mentioned in his post (first link).  Some things never change.

Comment: @BenVoigt have you seen an orange?

Comment: @HansPassant I don't want to babysit a chatroom and I can't judge if the caretakers are participating out of boredom or because they see the value of having a canonical library of Q/A;s. That said: I still think a lot of things go right and a few go wrong. A win here is that the things that do go wrong are noticed and are then discussed om meta. That should enable us to formulate guidance to the best of our abilities. I don't expect it ever to be easy but we'll keep trying for the next 6 to 8 weeks. I value your feedback, I'll see if I can transform that into something that is actionable .

Comment: Don't be shy with your down-votes. Distribute them liberally.

Comment: @cpburnz while I agree that down votes are a strong and often underused moderation tool the rules of SOCVR strictly prohibit asking for down (or up) votes on specific posts. Just FYI.

Comment: @rene I just meant this in general. Not in relation to the SOCVR.

Comment: @BenVoigt No one here is talking about NaA flags but you as far as I can see. These are answers that were deleted via delete votes from 20k+ rep users who reviewed the posts and voted to delete as was within their purview. The system handles consensus for us by requiring more than a single vote to delete things. The post you linked has absolutely nothing at all to do with delete votes.

Comment: @TinyGiant: Every time I re-read Braiam's answer, it still contains the phrase "not even a (partial) answer".  If that isn't the same as NAA I don't know what it is.  And [his comment under Servy's answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/375424#comment638856_375446), and Servy's reply, are both discussing whether the answer merits deletion specifically on NAA grounds.  And under the same answer, you mention that [it isn't NAA](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/375424#comment638891_375446), [twice](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/375424#comment639035_375446)

Comment: @BenVoigt I think it's because the [privilege article on delete votes](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/trusted-user) uses the same language as NAA flags: *The answer is extremely low quality: There is little to no scope for improvement. The answer doesn't attempt to answer the question; it may be a comment or a separate question altogether.*

Comment: There ought to be a FAQ expanding on when/how delete votes should be used because it doesn't seem like there's agreement on that.

Comment: @BSMP got had the right mindset that I was quoting the help center, just got the [wrong article](https://stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers). BTW, in all moments I was referring about reasons to delete answers, in no way I referenced the mechanism of deletion.

Comment: @BenVoigt what BSMP said plus this: I didnt say it wasn't NaA, I said that delete votes are not just NaA flags for users with 20k rep. I said that delete votes are for much more than what NaA flags are for.

Comment: @TinyGiant: That's "talking about NAA flags".

Comment: @BenVoigt by that I meant that you're the only one arguing about whether or not these should be flagged as NaA. Everyone else is arguing about whether or not such answers should be voted for deletion. Some people are saying that delete votes should only ever be used when NaA flags should be used and not in any other situations. My point is that all of this arguing is about the applicable criteria for delete votes, _not_ NaA flags, while you're arguing that these answers are not NaA... which is entirely besides the point regardless of whether that is true or not.

Comment: @TinyGiant: Well actually I was confronting a below-the-belt attack against Hans...  An attack from a user with a history of "doing their best to bypass consensus and just impose their will despite the fact it runs counter to consensus". Braiam habitually and repeatedly rejects consensus on NAA flags and this history is relevant to his reply to Hans. I'm not saying this is the same topic as NAA, but that **it is not acceptable to handle this topic the way Braiam handled NAA in the past**.  Of course, my comment linking evidence has been deleted but the attack on Hans hasn't...

Comment: @Adriaan I got the perfect title for this question: What should we do about oranges?

Answer (score 47):

I wouldn't regard the language of an answer as particularly important in many cases. I quite often search for information about Android or iOS, which I'm programming in C#. And often the questions and answers are in Swift, Objective-C, Java or whatever. They still give me the information I need. And sometimes people have added additional C# answers to questions that were framed in Swift or Java - and those are even more helpful to me. Occasionally questions were phrased in Xamarin/C#, but they got a Swift/Java answer, explaining the OS function to use: those are also helpful. So answers that don't match *my* language, and/or don't match the question language are still perfectly useful.

In general, the crux of many questions revolves around either: the concept of how to implement an algorithm; or the OS commands to use to achieve something. In both cases the language used isn't particularly important, and indeed pseudo-code may be quite adequate for the first. Questions where the meat of the question involves some technical detail of the language itself (such as details of type casting, inheritance, etc.) are probably rather in the minority.

So please don't go around the site deleting every, otherwise accurate, answer you find in the "wrong" language. Such vandalism would remove plenty of content that is useful to me.

That's not to say that answers in the correct language aren't better. And in *some* cases the details of the language are important, and might render an answer largely useless.

In the specific case you mention, you say it asks about an algorithm, and Java was only mentioned as a tag. It seems likely, therefore, that readers will find the question via Google quite easily if they are using other languages.  There's a good chance many, possibly even a majority, of the people arriving on the page are NOT using Java.

If the question wasn't good and already has numerous good answers, the answers in your case might be rather useless - but only because they are more fluff on a bad question.

And finally, regarding policy, my understanding was that inaccuracy was not a grounds for deleting an answer at all? Rather it should be downvoted, ideally with a comment explaining why the answer is wrong.

Comment: From this perspective, perhaps it's best to examine whether the question can be edited slightly to indicate Java solutions are *preferred* but others might be acceptable. In this case, though, the non-Java answers where in completely unrelated (though not necessarily incompatible) languages (Haskell and Python, respectively).

Comment: @TylerH: If you didn't know it was in a different language, and just treated the answer as pseudo-code, would it still be useful?  If it would be useful as pseudo-code, do not penalize the answerer for using pseudo-code  that he compiled and tested before posting.

Comment: @TylerH - I think however that's focusing too much on the preference of one user; and that's the logical contradiction in the actions here.  Braiam mentions in a comment under the question _"a group of users doing their best to shape the site how they consider is best for Stack Overflow"_  Sure, the original questioner wanted a Java answer and ideally he'll get one.  But for everyone else - all those arriving from google - other languages may be as useful or more so.  If interested in what's good for overall the community, the language of the OP doesn't seem important

Comment: As an aside. I've seen answers written in the language of a question, and then other authors add supplementary answers saying things such as "Here is XYZ's answer in Python..." or "This is the c# version...".  And those extra answers have received multiple upvotes.  They were clearly useful to (some of) the community, albeit probably not to the one person who asked the question.

Comment: This opinion appears to be very mobile specific. In web and desktop code, this sort of cross language usefulness is extremely *uncommon*. You'll typically implement the same thing in *very* different ways in different languages. The question mentions Python, C++, and Haskell, which are all rare on mobile and have very different norms and available functionality than Java. Barring actually invoking C++ from Python (which is not particularly uncommon for libraries), I expect that the answers would be irrelevant to each other.

Comment: Delete-voting answers is a [20k privilege/responsibility](/help/privileges/trusted-user). Part of that is to deletevote answers where "the answer is extremely low quality: There is little to no scope for improvement". That doesn't explicitly include technical inaccuracy, but it's commonly believed it does. However, technical inaccuracy isn't the point in this question (i.e. "inaccuracy" implies more than mismatched language; perhaps poor wording implicitly expanding your meaning). The question is about the language used in the answer not matching the language indicated by the question's tags.

Comment: @BenVoigt I don't typically find pseudo code answers very useful. Helpful answers take the time to provide an actual answer rather than a pseudo answer.

Comment: @TylerH: An answer explained using pseudo-code is not a "pseudo answer".   If you don't find it useful, it's probably because you haven't had exposure to computer science.  That's ok, many programmers haven't... but you're also missing out on a lot of the understanding.

Comment: @StuartWhitehouse I think you have to balance the sensibility of turning a question about Java with 15 Java answers into a question about Java with 15 answers and 15 other answers in 15 other different languages. At some point you should be asking a different question, and honestly I think if people want to know how to do something in 15 different languages, we should have 15 different questions. The whole point of Stack Overflow is that you get exactly the answer you want when searching/asking a question. Having to wade through 15 non-Java answers is no different from a bunch of forum chatter

Comment: @jpmc26: I feel like you weakened your point, that languages have different builtin functionality, by introducing platforms.  It really doesn't matter that my embedded board doesn't have nearly enough resources for python -- imperative code translates pretty directly to other imperative languages.  Fancy builtins may be a problem to replace, but equally so on a desktop.  And translation between functional and imperative isn't easy, but that has nothing to do with platform either.

Comment: @BenVoigt I don't disagree there is some merit to pseudo code over *no* code. I just expect answerers to try harder. If someone asks for pseudo code or doesn't specify a language, that's one thing. But if someone asks how to do something in Java, why bother posting pseudo code instead of just writing the answer in Java?

Comment: @TylerH: Because code is not an answer.  An explanation is an answer.  Code in the answer should facilitate the explanation, not copy+paste.  SO is an encyclopedia of answered questions, not a library of code snippets.

Comment: @BenVoigt That misses the point of my comment. In all instances of "answer" in my previous comments I am referring to answers with both code and accompanying explanatory text. I agree the code-only answers without any explanation, pseudo-code or otherwise, are problematic.

Comment: @TylerH: Bloated code does not facilitate the explanation.  Code which is short and to the point and not intermixed with boilerplate makes the answer easier to understand.  I disagree that providing a uncomplicated explanation is somehow "not trying hard enough".  Questions should be SSCCE because the person asking doesn't know what is relevant.  Answers should be more minimal than that, because the expert writing *does* know what is relevant.

Comment: @BenVoigt My mention of mobile is coincidental. Mobile is an arena where answers in different languages are much more likely to be relevant to each other because they are so dependent on the platform itself. That's just the nature of the technology. This is only the case in very specific circumstances on other platforms, like C# and VB.NET both targeting the .NET platform and being nearly functionally identical. Furthermore, the "fancy built ins" are *core features* of the Python language. Lose those conceptual building blocks, and the definition of the algorithm changes fundamentally.

Comment: @BenVoigt The issue with answerers writing pseudo code is that it is generally not useful for people who are in a state where they need help and thus are asking the question in the first place. There is a chasm of ability/knowledge that is created by unnecessary pseudo code answers, or the pseudo code is unnecessarily abstracted from the problem. If that is the best you can do, I understand, but I will still value non-pseudo code answers more, always.

Comment: @jpmc26 - it's not entirely mobile specific.  A glance through my favourited questions starts with a javascript language Q that has a couple of "if using library X you can" answers down the list.  Next is T-SQL, and 4 answers giving the equivalent syntax for other DB systems, all upvoted.  And then there's a large data algorithm Q tagged c# with a couple of answers with c# code, several with descriptions of algorithms, a couple with pseudo-code, and one SQL answer - again all upvoted, so useful to someone.

Comment: Then the technologies the question(s) are about in your case, are Android and iOS, not programming languages. If you post a question tagged Android and then get answers about MS Windows, they should be deleted.

Comment: @Lundin - but that's rather my point.  These were all questions tagged, eg, Objective-c (as well as iOS).  And may have contained partial code in Objective-c.  But the meat of the question was really the OS - and so when someone adds the Swift translation as an extra answer that is useful to many readers.  A question tagged ios10 may get supplementary answers "and in iOS 11 you can now..."  But OP implies they would delete all these.  The question that triggered this meta was _about an algorithm_ - and only mentioned Java when the poster was forced to add at least 1 tag.

Comment: So when someone adds a Haskell answer to that same question about android, that's fine? No it makes no sense and should be deleted.  That's what the OP says should be deleted. Answers that don't make any sense because they are written in a language completely irrelevant to the question. The most they will ever do is waste the time of those reading it. If someone wants to do it in Haskell, they should ask how to do it in Haskell. Not answers that target a different version of the same platform being asked about, or questions about a platform and get answers in multiple applicable languages.

Comment: @TinyGiant OP adds no such qualification as "_answers that don't make any sense because they are written in a language completely irrelevant to the question_".  Rather it is an absolute statement refering to ANY answer not matching the question tag.  And the phrase "technically correct" rather suggests pedantry at work.  If OP had asked about answers in a language fundamentally differing from the question language such that the answer was meaningless he may have gotten different answers.  If this meta had the answer "delete them" someone would use that to delete any such answer even if useful

Comment: There's also a confounding factor in this specific case that's it's not very clear that the question was ever intended to be Java specific.  As per S.L. Barth's comment under the question, it was _written_ in a language agnostic manner, and Java only added as a tag when the poster was forced to add a tag.  So it's plausible in this specific case it was actually intended to be largely language agnostic.  That's uncertain, but it seems to make the case for deleting other answers rather weak

Comment: @StuartWhitehouse if it had been language agnostic it would have been too broad. Either the question is off topic and we are all arguing about nothing or the answers are off topic and should be deleted. The answers are in fact written in languages that are meaningless to the question asked, so your whole argument suggests pedantry at work.

Comment: @TinyGiant - but it _was_ (allegedly) too broad.  The same people who deleted the answers also closed the question as too broad - hence Hans' quibbling about the apparent contradiction.  However this meta question isn't about the fate of one answer - a diamond mod has already decided that by undeleting it.  This meta question is phrased as a policy question of how to deal with such answers (plural) in general, and implies a fairly robotic: answer language does match tag in question -> delete answer.

Comment: @StuartWhitehouse Even in that case I would still lean towards deletion. Remember that an answer must be at -1 to be deleted, so anyone can upvote the answer and prevent the casting of delete votes. This isn't like people are out deleting highly voted answers, they're deleting answers that the community has already said are not useful. The moderator's decision in this case is... questionable. The fact that it was closed is regrettable in my opinion; but the case still stands: if the answer is in a different language and is scored -1, it's open for delete votes.

Comment: Related: [A moderator declined two of my NAA flags on the same post](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/359863)

Answer (score 25):

If you think a given answer is unhelpful, then you should be downvoting it.  You shouldn't be deleting answers because you don't think they're good answers to the question.

Whether an answer in a different language is still useful is a matter of opinion, and opinion that you're more than welcome to reflect with your votes on the post, and that others will be able to voice *their* opinions on.  It's a very context-dependent issue.  Some answers in other languages can be very useful, some aren't.  Either way, deleting is not how you reflect your opinion of the usefulness of an answer.

Comment: "You shouldn't be deleting answers because you don't think they're good answers to the question." There's nothing in the entire site, except this answer that suggest this. The criteria for deleting answers is a non-exhaustive list which use the language of "do not fundamentally answer **the question**".

Comment: @Braiam Posts being not an answer doesn't mean, "I don't think this is a good answer to the question", it means, "this answer isn't attempting to answer the question".  It means things like clarifying questions, or people asking new questions, or replies to other answers, not answers that, in your opinion, are incorrect or unhelpful.  There *is* a mechanism for indicating that you think an answer is incorrect or unhelpful, downvotes.

Comment: I think delete votes (in combination with downvotes) are the proper way to deal with content that is low quality but doesn't qualify for flagging. I would consider an answer that provides a solution in a language other than the language being asked about to be a low quality language. It's not Not an Answer, and it's not Very Low Quality, but it is Low Quality (in my opinion) and if the community decides to downvote and delete vote it then that is the prerogative of the community. You can disagree that such answers are Low Quality and vote accordingly if you like.

Comment: @TinyGiant The problem is that deleting answers because you think they aren't good answers *prevents* others from even being able to reflect their opinion of their quality, because the answer is no longer there to be voted on.

Comment: Especially when a group act together to cast multiple delete votes rapidly.  Such block voting seems to entirely side-step the ability of the community as a whole to express an opinion

Comment: @StuartWhitehouse 10K-ers can hangout on  [/Tools](https://stackoverflow.com/tools?tab=Delete&daterange=today) and achieve the same effect. If timing is an issue create a feature request that prevents delete votes in quick succession. Keep in mind that will also block quick deletion of posts where we all agree on the needed outcome.

Comment: @rene The problem here is not the quick deletion of bad content, the problem is deletion, whether quick or slow, of content that doesn't merit deletion.  Basically anything that should actually be deleted, should be deleted as quickly as possible.

Comment: @Servy I totally agree.

Comment: This is rules for the sake of rules. Not practical application of those rules. A Python answer has no business on a vanilla Java question. It does not answer the question; it is pure clutter.

Comment: @jpmc26 And yet several people have given examples of answers using other languages that were very helpful in solving their problem, so clearly that's just not true in a general sense.  And of course I may feel that lots of various attempts to answer a question, even using the language the post is tagged with, aren't useful answers, and I might feel that the answer has no business being there.  The difference is that I don't feel that just because I'm of the opinion that it's not useful others shouldn't even be allowed to express their own opinions.

Comment: @Servy Exactly. Your answer is phrased as an absolute, but it's context dependent. There are also examples of when another language is totally irrelevant to the question. Would you accept an [tag:r] answer to a [tag:pandas] question? I wouldn't. They're too disconnected, despite being suitable for similar purposes. It wouldn't answer the question and deserves to be deleted.

Comment: @jpmc26 Whether a given answer is useful or not, as a result of using a different language than the question is tagged with, is absolutely content dependent, and cannot be answered in absolutes.  That an answer to the question should be allowed to be judged on its merits, and not deleted because you personally don't think it's a useful answer, is *not* context dependent.  If you think that, in context, the answer is useful, upvote it, and if you don't, then downvote it.  You don't delete answers just because you don't think they're useful answers.

Comment: @Servy You delete content that has no place where it is. Or you move it. The idea that we should clutter all of our questions with totally irrelevant content is just going to make the site a mess. Why do you want it to be a mess? Sure, sometimes that's opinion based. It's not opinion based that a Java answer is irrelevant to a typical Python question. Besides that, Python developers wouldn't necessarily be experienced enough to evaluate the quality of a Java answer; that answer needs to be in front of Java experts, in a Java question.

Comment: @jpmc26 Are there so many people posting answers that aren't useful, as a result of using the wrong language, that they're obscuring useful answers?  Do you have examples of cases where people aren't able to get the solution to their problem because others are posting answers in other languages?  It's not about wanting the site to be a mess, it's about wanting the community to be able to give feedback on the quality of actual answers, rather than having a few people decide that since they don't like it, no one else should even be allowed to weigh in on it.

Comment: @Servy The question itself describes a post that contained at least 4 different languages in the answers. Yes, that is so messed up that it's preventing the normal working of the site. The experts that should be evaluating those answers will not see them because of tag filtering. Unless you're advocating for tagging with all the languages, which would make it categorically Too Broad.

Comment: @jpmc26 Now you're just describing a code dump answer, in which the answer is in a different language than the question.  Honestly I find most such answers to not be useful even if they're in the  *right* language.  If, however, it's an answer that explains the problem, how to approach solving it, in clear simple steps, often no code is needed at all.  If there is some examples provided in another language, the answer may well be a useful answer even if people can't understand the code at all (or just treat it as pseudocode, which is basically what you should do in such situations).

Comment: @jpmc26 Since we have no actual question we can't possibly say how useful the answers are.  The OP thinks they weren't useful.  Maybe others thought they were.  Or if the community as a whole largely felt they weren't useful, and they acted appropriately and downvoted them to reflect that opinion, then those answers wouldn't have impacted readers' ability to find good answers, as the good answers would all have been shown first.

Comment: @Servy If the question doesn't require code to answer, then a port of example code to other languages is clearly very low quality and worth deleting as it's not an answer to the original question. However, implementations usually differ significantly between languages simply because of their norms and APIs. This means that questions that don't target a specific language are nearly always Too Broad to begin with.

Comment: @Servy the same argument applies against NaA, VLQ, and even spam. Deleting any of those things prevents others from being able to reflect their opinion of whether or not it is NaA, VLQ, or spam. We don't need the entire community's opinion about whether or not a given answer is low quality (therefor warranting deletion) or not. We only need the consensus of as many people as is required by the system. I've never seen anywhere that we shouldn't use delete votes for low quality content, and if those voting believe that such an attempted answer is low quality then a delete vote is warranted.

Comment: @jpmc26 If  you feel that the differences in the languages, with respect to solving the problem being asked about, are so significant that the solutions and approaches described are not useful in attempting to solve the problem in the language requested, then that's a great argument for why you think the question isn't useful.  You have a mechanism *specifically* to indicate that you don't think the answer is useful; downvote it.  Other people can then cast their own votes based on their opinion of its usefulness.

Comment: @TinyGiant The quality of an answer is a subjective matter of opinion for subject matter experts to express.  Something being spam or NAA is, with rare exceptions, an objective analysis of the post, and something for which it has wide consensus as meriting deletion as a result.

Comment: _"The quality of an answer is a subjective matter of opinion for subject matter experts to express."_ Yes and they can express their opinion with delete votes or undelete votes if they have that privilege. Once the required number of votes in either direction is satisfied then the post will be deleted or undeleted. This is how the system was designed to work and you're saying that these experts _shouldn't_ be able to express their opinion because you disagree with their opinion?

Comment: @Servy Java experts shouldn't be expressing their opinion on the quality of a Python answer in the first place, unless they are also Python experts, in which case they can do so *on a Python question*. The large differences between languages is why we have a community norm of dividing questions by language, even if they appear to be performing the same task, in the first place. These delete votes enforce that norm, and they are thus appropriate for the same reasons that we have the norm to begin with.

Comment: @TinyGiant No, I'm saying that delete votes isn't how you express your opinion of the usefulness of a post.  It's how you indicate something isn't an answer at all, not that it's an answer that you don't think is useful.

Comment: @jpmc26 What are you talking about?  Where am I encouraging people to express an opinion on answers to problems they're not knowledgeable about?  And I'm not saying that we shouldn't have language tags or that there's no need for people to ask how to solve a given problem in different languages.  All I've said is that you don't delete answers just because you don't think they're useful answers to the question.  You downvote answers to indicate you don't think they're useful answers.

Comment: @Servy Where you suggest a Python answer should not be deleted from a question specifically asking about and tagged with Java. It only belongs there if Java experts have the expertise to evaluate it, and if it doesn't belong there, deleting it is not only acceptable, but desirable.

Comment: @jpmc26 If the answer provides a useful answer for the question asked, which is a java problem, then Java experts should be qualified to evaluate it.  If the answer isn't useful to people with suitable expertise in the problem being asked about, then *they can downvote the answer to indicate that it's not a useful solution to the question asked*.  By your logic, they shouldn't delete it because they're not qualified to judge it at all.

Comment: @Servy They're qualified to judge the relevance of a Python answer to a Java question, which is virtually always none.

Comment: @jpmc26 Again, numerous people have given examples of situations in which they've found examples of answers in a different language to the question to have been helpful.  If you personally think that a given answer isn't useful because of the languages it uses, you can reflect that opinion with a vote, but it doesn't mean everyone universally thinks that every single post using a different language is bad.  Judge answers on their merits, rather than making absolute statements about how they're always bad, when evidence shows that it's just not true in this siutation.

Comment: @jpmc26 You even say in your own answers that it's content dependent, so why are you now saying that you should always delete them without even thinking about it?

Comment: Look. You're trying to argue technicalities here, which was my original point to begin with. A Python answer to a vanilla Java question is on the level of "I like turtles." It just has nothing to do with the question asked. If we want SO to have any semblance of being organized, we should clean that sort of cruft up. Sure, in some contexts, that's not the case (as I argue in my answer). But it most certainly is not the case most of the time, and there's no reason we should refrain from engaging in useful clean up efforts. Broken windows beget more broken windows; let's just fix them.

Comment: @jpmc26 So since you believe that this issue isn't context dependent, and that answers should be deleted regardless of usefulness and without considering their context, do you want to amend your answer accordingly?  You might think that an answer including code not in the question means that it can't possibly have anything to do with the question asked, others disagree, and have found plenty of cases where it's useful.  Deletion, and other such clean up efforts, are for things that *aren't answers*, not for answers that you just don't like.

Comment: @Servy I believe they should be deleted if they do not answer the question. If the question asked for Java, then Python won't answer it, no matter how many people think the answer is useful. If it's *really* that useful, we can preserve it in a CW question and answer about Python, but it shouldn't be left in a question where it does not belong. The idea that it can't be deleted because it answers some question that is unrelated is utterly ridiculous and impractical. Usefulness is not the *only* consideration ever, and we can increase the usefulness by organizing content.

Comment: @jpmc26 So why should your opinion that the answer isn't useful be able to override everyone else's opinion that it's a useful answer to the question?  Why are you opposed to expressing your opinion on the usefulness of the post *using the mechanism that specifically exists for expressing opinions on the usefulness of a post*?  And again, since you apparently think this is not in fact context dependent, and that it's always inherently wrong no matter what, you should amend your answer accordingly.

Comment: @Servy Why should drive by voters' opinions override the opinion of veterans who are much better at generating and organizing content than they are? We could play this game all day.

Comment: @jpmc26 It doesn't.  You don't need to prevent other people from being allowed to express their opinions in order for you to be allowed to express yours.  Also, that statement falsely implies that all experts support your position and all uninformed users oppose it, which is demonstrably not true.

Comment: @Servy 1) _"No, I'm saying that delete votes isn't how you express your opinion of the usefulness of a post."_ Ok, maybe, but delete votes _are_ a method of expressing your opinion about the quality of the post. If a posts quality is below par and is unlikely to be salvaged, it is within the subject matter expert's purview to vote to delete.

Comment: @Servy 2) _"It's how you indicate something isn't an answer at all, not that it's an answer that you don't think is useful."_ Again, I'll give you that it may or may not be acceptable to use delete votes to express opinions on the usefulness of a post (debatable), but delete votes are definitely _not_ limited to just answers that aren't attempts to answer the question, that is the NaA flag. Delete votes _can_ be used for that, but they can also be used for other things like ...

Comment: ... duplicate answers, low quality answers, bad answers, answers that suggest doing very bad things in a misleading manner, answers that are technically inaccurate or altogether incorrect, etc, etc.

Comment: If you ask a question about Java and I answer with the perfect recipe for scones, my answer should be deleted, no matter how much you like scones. An off-topic answer is per definition unhelpful and possibly harmful. That being said, answers in a different programming language are not necessarily off-topic, depending on context.

Comment: @TinyGiant If you think an answer is wrong, or otherwise unhelpful, then by all means, downvote it, or post a comment on what you think is wrong with it.  But just because you think it's wrong doesn't mean others should be prohibited from even expressing their opinion on it at all.  Lots of people are incorrect in their assertion that an answer is wrong, and there can *certainly* be differing opinions on how useful an answer is.  Again, you have multiple means of providing feedback on the post.  That doesn't mean you should prevent anyone from having that ability.

Comment: @Lundin Since answers using another programming language aren't off topic, why even bring up answers that are just entirely unrelated to the question?  What's the point in posting a comment that's entirely unrelated to the issue that we're discussing here?

Comment: Of course they are off-topic. https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic is not an exhaustive list. Similarly, giving an answer in another language than English is off-topic too, even though the above link doesn't say so.

Comment: @Lundin And yet there are plenty of examples where they're helpful answers to the question asked, so no, you *can't* just say that they're off topic when they *answer the question*.

Comment: @Servy Btw, "So since you believe that this issue isn't context dependent, and that answers should be deleted regardless of usefulness and without considering their context, do you want to amend your answer accordingly?" is obviously a willful misrepresentation of the point I'm making. I've been using a specific, clear cut example to argue against your absolute position that they should *never* be deleted. Since we agree that there are some cases where deletion is unwarranted, there was no reason for us to spend time debating that point.

Comment: @jpmc26 No, you're not using a specific example.  You're providing an entire broad category of questions and saying you should *always* delete questions where those languages don't line up, without any consideration for context.  If you linked to a specific answer, explained its context, and why, in that context, you feel the answer should be deleted, *that* would be a specific example incorporating the context.

Comment: @Servy I completely disagree and reject your nonsensically restrictive view on the use of delete votes. Delete votes are for low quality content, saying that we shouldnt use our delete votes on content that we deem low quality is just plain nonsense. When I'm delete voting I'm not preventing anyone from doing anything. The system stops them from doing those things once it has determined that consensus has been reached.

Comment: @TinyGiant And I completely disagree with your treatment of delete votes as just being what 20k users are supposed to do instead of downvoting posts.  If you think a post is low quality there is a mechanism specifically for that.  Downvotes.  Delete votes are not just "downvotes for users with 20k reputation", as you're claiming they should be used.

Comment: Delete votes are most definitely for low quality content. That's what they're for, what they've always been for. They are **not** just extra NaA flags for 20k+ users as you're claiming they should be used.

Comment: @TinyGiant "When I'm delete voting I'm not preventing anyone from doing anything. The system stops them from doing those things once it has determined that consensus has been reached." That's like saying if I, and a few other people I know, all flag all of your posts as spam we're not preventing you from doing anything, it's just the system.  The system is doing those things in response to a mechanism being mis-used.  When you're casting delete votes just because you think a post should be downvoted, you're causing the system to incorrectly delete something that shouldn't be deleted.

Comment: Well absolutely if you abuse the system then the system is going to work incorrectly. Using delete votes for low quality content is not an abuse, it's what they're for. It's their purpose. It's the entire reason they exist.

Comment: @TinyGiant No, that's what downvotes are for.  If the intent was for things that people thought weren't useful to be deleted, then answers would just get deleted when they were downvoted enough, rather than having an entirely separate deletion and downvote system in place.  Deleting is there for answers that have problems beyond your opinion of their usefulness as an answer.

Comment: @Servy no, because then we would be allowing any group of 125 rep users to delete anything. Limiting the deletion to delete votes that are only used by users with more than 20k reputation means that there is quite a bit more restriction on who gets to vote to delete  stuff. None of that changes the fact that delete votes are for low quality content, not that the entire purpose of delete votes is to delete low quality content. To suggest that would be nonsensical, as I've said repeatedly.

Comment: Show me something from the help center that says "don't cast delete votes on low quality content".

Comment: @TinyGiant Show me something from the help center that says, "cast a delete vote on every answer that you think is low quality".

Comment: @Servy sure, the [trusted user privilege page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/trusted-user) says: _"**Deleting answers: When should I vote to delete an answer?** You may vote to delete answers in the following cases: The answer is extremely low quality; and there is little to no scope for improvement. ..."_

Comment: @TinyGiant Just repeating that you think it's nonsensical to delete things that have problems beyond just their technical merits and quality as an answer, and that you think people shouldn't be using votes, which *specifically exist for precisely the purpose of expressing one's opinion on the quality of an answer* doesn't make it true.  You think it's nonsensical to use the tool specifically created to indicate quality as the means of indicating quality, I think it's nonsensical to refuse to use the tool that expressly exists to indicate quality as the means of indicating quality.

Comment: @TinyGiant But that's not what you said.

Comment: ... I never said any of that. I said people _should_ be using their delete votes for such things. I never said they shouldnt. I never said that people should not use their votes to express their opinion of the quality of a post. Downvotes and delete votes are not mutually exclusive, in fact I'd hazard a guess to say that most delete votes are accompanied by a downvote.

Comment: @Servy it is what I said, you should use delete votes on low quality content. An answer in a different language is extremely low quality with little to no scope for improvement.

Comment: @TinyGiant "you should use delete votes on low quality content" But that's not what you quoted says.  It doesn't say, you should be delete voting every post you think is of low quality.  It says you should be casting delete votes on content that's *extremely* bad, a word that has an important distinction, and also for content that is *unsalvagably* bad.  That's not at all the same as saying you should be casting delete votes on everything you think isn't a good answer.

Comment: @TinyGiant And yet numerous people have given examples of cases where answers using code from another language are helpful and answer the question, so your statement that they're of extremely low quality and are unsalvageable are both false.

Comment: An answer to a question in a different language is extremely low quality and there is little to no scope for improvement. Works for me.

Comment: @TinyGiant But that's not true, as numerous people have given examples to show.

Comment: Feel free to express your opinion with your votes, as I am free to express my opinion with my votes. Just because you or others disagree that such content is extremely low quality doesn't mean that I'm inherently wrong. We get to vote on it, and the system decides who is right.

Comment: @TinyGiant there's an important difference between "low quality" which is the phrase you've been using and "extremely low quality".  Furthermore those deletion guidelines address the issue of off-topic/NaA type issues in the following bullet, "The answer doesn't attempt to answer the question; it may be a comment or a separate question altogether".  And that's very restrictive language, AFAIK identical to the NaA flag language.

Comment: And regarding "Feel free to express your opinion with your votes, as I am free to express my opinion with my votes" etc... the issue with actions leading up to this meta Q, was that a group were acting in a way that prevented anyone expressing an opinion.  By operating as a group to rapidly delete posts, no-one else did have a say.

Comment: @StuartWhitehouse extremely low quality is a subset of low quality. You can safely assume that I meant extremely low quality but excluded that word for brevity. I still consider answers that attempt to answer the question in a language other than the specified language to be extremely low quality. You can express your opinion of whether or not such an answer is extremely low quality by voting to delete or undelete such answers as you see fit. Note that upvoting such answers raises the number of delete votes required to delete an answer.

Comment: @StuartWhitehouse About the deletion guidelines I linked, that is a list, so if it fits either of those two points then users who have that privilege can cast a delete vote. Therefor if I deem an answer to be of sufficiently low quality and there is little to no scope for improvement, then I can cast a delete vote if I have that privilege.

Comment: @StuartWhitehouse Finally, the group who voted to delete this answer expressed their opinion via votes after discussion. There is a page for recently deleted answers that any 10k+ user can view, and any 20k+ user viewing the question can vote to undelete. No one is prevented from voting to undelete the answer. As said elsewhere, the same thing can happen if a bunch of 20k+ users were to sit on the recent delete votes page of the 10k tools and express their opinion on all recent delete votes in complete isolation. That there is a discussion around the deletion is not a bad thing.

Comment: "answers that suggest doing very bad things in a misleading manner, answers that are technically inaccurate or altogether incorrect"... It's actually better to allow these to remain with a very negative score.  If you delete them, someone else will come along and post the exact same bad idea and then it'll have a zero score.

Comment: @BenVoigt that is your opinion and your delete votes and undelete votes should reflect your opinion. My opinion is that they should be deleted, just like all the repeat nonsense answers to the chuck norris color css question. Yeah people post them again but that just means you have to keep cleaning up the mess, not give up on the mess altogether. Curation is an ongoing effort, not a one and done kind of thing.

Comment: Creating work for the future, and in the meantime sending the wrong signal to readers, is objectively making the site worse, less informative, less useful.

Comment: @BenVoigt so... like leaving extremely low quality answers (that will only at best ever waste people's time), for other people to clean up, yeah I could see how that would objectively make the site worse, less informative, and less useful. I'm glad we agree.

Comment: @TinyGiant But that's not what we're talking about.  We're talking about leaving answers that you don't like, but that lots of other people find helpful, informative, and correct answers to the question, but that you don't like as a matter of principle without even considering their value or usefulness.

Comment: @Servy But that's not what we're talking about. We're talking about answers that the community has already said are not helpful, informative, or correct by voting the answer down to the score of -1 or lower where it can be voted for deletion. If we were talking about answers that "lots of other people" find helpful, informative, and correct then the answers wouldn't be eligible for deletion at all because they would be upvoted past the score of delete vote eligibility, or at least not downvoted to that score.

Comment: @TinyGiant We're talking about *all* answers using a different language than the question is tagged with.  Of those, some are upvoted.  You're saying you want all of them to be deleted, even though many of them are upvoted, and quite helpful.  Additionally, of the answers that are useful and quality answers to the question, will always start out at a score of 0, because all answers do, so when you downvote and delete every single one of them unconditionally, you can end up deleting them before others that find them useful have a chance to upvote them.

Comment: @Servy no I'm saying that if subject matter experts deem the answer to be of extremely low quality due to the fact that the answer is in a language other than the language asked about, and the answer is eligible for deletion (meaning downvoted), said subject matter experts should be "trusted" (given that they are trusted users) to vote to delete said answer. You're saying that even though the answer has been voted below -1, and subject matter experts have deemed the answer to be extremely low quality for said reason, said subject matter experts should not be allowed to vote to delete it.

Comment: _"so when you downvote and delete every single one of them unconditionally, you can end up deleting them before others that find them useful have a chance to upvote them."_ _You_ also have to be a "trusted user" to do so, meaning that you've earned the trust to do just that, and no non-diamond moderators can unilaterally delete anything, so regardless it still takes more than one person (IIRC 3) to agree on the deletion and vote to delete before anyone else can upvote the answer. Given that there are so many more users who can upvote than can delete vote, this seems like arguing about nothing.

Comment: If you think the system is unfair, you should suggest a change to the system that would make it fair. Telling people that they should not express their opinion because their opinion differs from yours is... nonsense. Or is your opinion somehow worth more than everyone else's opinions?

Comment: @TinyGiant Trusted users are trusted to know not to delete answers just because they think they're not useful.  Also a user having 20k rep doesn't make them a subject matter expert.  I have 20k rep, and I'm not a subject matter expert in every question on the site.  A 20k user is experienced enough in the site to know what types of answers *aren't actual answers*, and to delete them without requiring moderator intervention.

Comment: @TinyGiant I'm not telling people not to express their opinion.  I'm telling them to express their opinion using the correct tool provided to them for expressing their opinion, rather than abusing tools that they are trusted to use correctly to delete posts that don't merit deletion.

Comment: I'm not saying that all 20k users should go on a delete vote rampage across the site. I specifically said that subject matter experts that have 20k+ rep should be allowed to express their opinion of the quality of answers to questions within the realm of their expertise. A trusted user is given the privilege to vote to delete answers that would not otherwise qualify for flags, they are not given delete votes to vote to delete answers that would be deleted much quicker using flags. Delete votes are **not** extra NaA flags for 20k+ rep users.

Comment: _"I'm telling them to express their opinion using the correct tool provided to them for expressing their opinion"_ In _your_ opinion such answers are not extremely low quality, but in my opinion they are. I am allowed to express my opinion in that matter just as you are: with delete or undelete votes. Your opinion differing from my opinion does not mean that I should not be able to express my opinion, nor does it mean that you can call my use of delete votes an abuse just because you don't agree that such answers are extremely low quality.

Comment: What you get to do if you disagree with my opinion of whether or not an answer is extremely low quality is to vote it up if it is not yet deleted and vote to undelete it if it is. You don't get to demonize those who disagree with you.

Comment: @TinyGiant Yes, subject matter experts *are* given a means to express their opinion on the quality of answers.  That means is upvotes and downvotes.

Comment: You're saying that subject matter experts with more than 20k+ rep should not use delete votes for answers that they deem to be of extremely low quality. That is exactly the opposite of  what the help center states delete votes should be used for.

Comment: @TinyGiant That's like saying I'm allowed to express my opinion that every single one of your answers is spam, and if you disagree then that's just your opinion and it's inappropriate of you to tell me that I can't flag your answers as spam if I think they should be deleted and for you to lose 100 reputation per post.

Comment: @TinyGiant No, I'm saying that you thinking that an answer being wrong or not useful doesn't make it "extremely low quality".

Comment: If you think that every one of my answers is spam then you should flag them all as spam. Of course every one of those spam flags will end up in front of a moderator and they will probably disagree, declining all of your flags and leaving you with a flag ban.

Comment: @Servy that is your opinion. In my opinion an answer being technically inaccurate or altogether wrong, or being written in a different language than what was asked about, makes it extremely low quality.

Comment: @TinyGiant And if I find a few friends of mine who also are of the opinion that your posts are spam then your posts will all just get deleted, and you'll lose all of your reputation.

Comment: @Servy still that would raise automatic flags for moderator review and they would probably find that to be fraud, in which case you and all of your friends would get flag bans and all of the posts would be undeleted. (I recall this happening previously)

Comment: @TinyGiant So you're saying that the use of moderation tools aren't actually things that anyone can use just because in their opinion they should be, and that it's actually abuse to use moderation tools in situations in which they're not designed to be used.  I can't just say, "In my opinion all of your answers are spam, so it's not abuse for me to flag them as spam" and be shielded from any accusations of abuse.

Comment: @Servy it always comes down to your personal opinion or "analysis" (it's still an opinion) of the post. If you honestly, truly believe that every one of my answers is spam then it is your duty to flag them as such. That does not mean that you would be right, it means that you are moderating based on your analysis of the post. My analysis of answers that answer in a language other than what is asked about is that they are extremely low quality, and therefor I should down vote and delete vote as such. If it is your analysis that they are not, then you should upvote / undelete vote.

Comment: If you were to find that all of your spam flags on my answers were declined, you would probably reexamine your definition of spam. If I were to find all of the answers I had delete voted to be upvoted and not deleted, I may consider reexamining my definition of extremely low quality. If you were to find all of the answers that you upvote to be downvoted and deleted, you may consider reexamining your definition of extremely low quality. The system is designed to work, we don't need you demonizing people for doing what they believe is right.

Comment: @TinyGiant But if you see a meta question asking if it's appropriate to delete answers just because you think they're not useful, you would consider it inappropriate for people to give any answer on that topic, because telling other people how to use their votes is wrong, and if you saw overwhelming support in favor of answers saying that an answer including code from a language not tagged in the question isn't grounds for deletion, it's not a reason to re-examine your position that they should be deleted and is instead grounds to comment on that answer saying they shouldn't demonize people.

Comment: _"You shouldn't be deleting answers because you don't think they're good answers to the question."_ I think NaA, VLQ, and spam answers are not good answers to the question. I also think they are not useful. That's not why I NaA, VLQ, or spam flag them. I flag them as NaA, VLQ, or spam because based on my analysis they are NaA, VLQ, or spam. I don't delete vote answers that answer the question in a language other than that asked for because I think they are not useful, even though I do think that. I delete vote them because they are extremely low quality.

Comment: Your answer doesn't argue that such answers are not extremely low quality, your answer argues that delete votes should not be used to express opinions on the usefullness of a post which is besides the point. The delete votes were used to express the analysis of subject matter experts that the posts were extremely low quality.

Comment: You're saying that because you don't agree that they are extremely low quality, they can't possibly be extremely low quality, and therefor everyone must just not like the posts and they're all voting on the usefulness of the post and whether or not they personally like the post using the wrong tool, which is just wrong. That is to say if I don't agree with you then my opinion is not a valid opinion.

Comment: @TinyGiant Did you miss the fact that this whole question is about the fact that a moderator specifically undeleted the post, indicating that it's inappropriate of the 20k users to have deleted the answer.  I've given my explanation as to why.  You don't like it.  That's not really anything I can do anything about, but that's the way the system works.  Your continued assertion that the behavior is okay, even though both the moderator handling the situation, as well as the community in general (based on the feedback to the meta post), do not support your position, doesn't make it okay.

Answer (score 10):

For C# and VB.NET, sometimes an OP will be happy with an answer in either language even if they don't state so in the question because the question is more to do with the framework rather than the language. Sometimes they won't.

It is often not onerous to translate between the two if the answerer didn't notice the language and the OP doesn't currently understand the other one.

So *sometimes* it is OK with *that* pair of languages.

Comment: Good  point. Although you should delete the answer/question for using VB.NET ;)

Comment: The same is true for Managed C++, F#, IronPython or any .NET language, as long as the question has to do with the framework and not the language syntax or unique features in the language. Admittedly, C# and VB.NET have almost complete language feature parity, so it's easier to convert between one and the other.

Comment: they ARE diverging slowly.  Someone i know used an automatic conversion tool plugin in vb,net and had 147 errors afterwards.

Comment: @JohnLord: 99% likelihood those were caused by bugs in the conversion tool, and not feature differences between the languages.

Comment: one that springs to mind immediately is that you can not declare an array in c# directly while using an index that is another variable.  You can do this in vb.net.  C# required him to rework it into declaring an arraylist and outputting that to an array.

Comment: Another is you can't declare enums inside interfaces in c#, but can in vb - that really causes an automatic converter problems!

Comment: @JohnLord: I'm having a hard time visualizing a situation that would be an array declaration in one language and require a List<T> in another (and ArrayList is never ever needed).  The situations where the index is variable can be done via assignment into the array after creation (which is what array initializers do anyway, because .NET does not support initialized arrays, they are always created empty and then filled in)

Comment: @StuartWhitehouse: Nested types in .NET are an interesting beast.  Nesting doesn't survive the compilation process, they get converted to an independent type in the namespace combined with a private-access permission (similar to `friend` in C++).  And an interface has no private members to give access to, so a type nested inside an interface is no different from an funny-named type in the same namespace.

Comment: well i posted that example from a college professor telling me that, but i was actually unable to reproduce it.  Redimensioning arrays IS a valid comparison though.  vb has a keyword "Preserve" that doesn't exist in c# and c# resizes arrays with a .resize method that vb doesn't have.

Comment: @ZevSpitz Nitpicking here, but C++/CLI could be a giant mess of incompatibility for a C# question if not done properly; unlike C#, all of C++ is in C++/CLI, including the parts of C++ that C# has no real substitute for.

Answer (score 6):

It is completely context dependent. There is no general answer.

- For mobile, answers that demonstrate the OS functionality required might be useful even if presented in another language.
- Some languages/frameworks are designed to target the same platform from the get go (e.g., C# and VB.NET both target .NET, Swift and Objective-C are both used for iOS). Thus it's often useful to be able to translate between them and answers given in another language than the asking one may still be relevant.
- Meanwhile, Python and Java have almost nothing in common unless you're way out in [left field](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/left_field) using [Jython](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jython). Their norms and standard APIs are so different that a Python answer to a Java question is irrelevant and vice versa. If someone wants to approach the same problem in each language, those belong in different questions because the answers will probably be completely disparate.

So the answer is **evaluate the context**. If there's *some* link between the languages that means the answer informs the question as originally asked and developers of the question's original language can reasonably evaluate the quality of the answer, then it is a valid answer. If not, it's invalid and belongs as an answer on another question that is appropriately tagged with target language and relevant libraries.

Comment: Does "context" include a couple of answers with different working implementations in the mentioned language, and others simply translating it to Python/C#/Brainfuck/whatever? Or even making an honest attempt in a different language, but being the 6th or later answer, thus down the list in the noise?

Comment: @Adriaan No. If I need a Python implementation of an algorithm that happens to have a working Java implementation, that's a new question. Python's norms and API are so different that the entire approach might need to be adjusted. A naïve port may make for a poor answer to that question, so it needs to be in a question tagged with that language so experts can review it.

Comment: I think your first 2 are rather the same point, although narrowing it down unnecessarily.  The logic applies to any API addressable from various languages - it could be the OS whether mobile or desktop, the .net framework, or various web services.  I agree though that the usefulness of a wrong language does depend.  But this meta question was phrased as "it was in the wrong language, therefore we deleted it", rather than "it was in a different language which behaves very differently and therefore..."

Comment: @StuartWhitehouse They're example situations, not points of argument. The fact that evaluation needs to be made is the point of saying it's context dependent.

Comment: No need to use Jython. You can run Python on the JVM with GraalVM. But if it's an algorithm question, and you give me a Python solution, I can just port it to Java. I'd rather have a working Python / Haskell / Elixir / Smalltalk solution I need to port than no answer to my algorithm question. Guess what people, polyglot programmers are a thing.

Answer (score 2):

This is very simple.

If the question is such that only answers in the listed programming language are relevant, answers in different programming languages are off-topic and should be deleted. They are not only unhelpful, they are actively harmful. A perfect example is C++ answers to C questions.

Otherwise, if a question is about a certain technology used by many different languages, or if it is a [language-agnostic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/language-agnostic) question with examples in one particular language, answers in different languages are fine.

NOTE: If a question was *previously* tagged with multiple languages but has been edited, answers in one of the previously listed languages should be left alone. Thus we must always check edit history of the question before deleting answers.

Answer (score -3):

In the scenario you described I would question whether or not the moderator realized the answer you deleted was in a different programming language.

If I had asked a question and tagged a specific programming language, I would expect all answers to be offered in that programming language.  If I had not specified a language, I would expect answers to be offered in whatever language the person answering was most comfortable with.

If a programming language is specified by the OP I would consider any answers provided in other languages to be incorrect/not an answer.

Comment: A language was specified, not through literal mention in the text, but by adding the [tag:java] tag. The mod would know about that, provided comments on the answer are visible in whatever flag-handle dialogue mods get; as the first sentence in the answer was "This is my Haskell implementation" and a comment was posted stating that the question was in java.

Comment: So if you're asking about an algorithm you'll consider pseudo-code to not be an answer? I'd say it's an attempt at showing you how to solve the problem, now you just need to translate the code.

Comment: @ivarni, I would only consider pseudo-code not an answer if I specifically indicated a language.  If I didn't specify a language, pseudo-code (or any language the person was familiar with) would be perfectly acceptable.

Comment: i would probably just downvote the wrong languages

Comment: Not An Answer is for things that are not attempts to answer the question, not for answers that you think are wrong, unhelpful, incorrect, or otherwise not a *good* answer to the question.

Comment: I stand corrected.  I was using my own interpretation of what an answer should be.  I looked around a little bit and found [this explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/185073/how-do-i-properly-use-the-not-an-answer-flag) of how to properly use the NAA flag.

Comment: @BenBloodworth Good that you realized that. I'd also recommend reading [this MSE post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/225370/your-answer-is-in-another-castle-when-is-an-answer-not-an-answer?rq=1) about how to classify between as answers, non-answers, and low-quality posts.

Comment: Note that the answer linked is still [highly disputed](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/310729/213575) because in other communities they consider anything that doesn't address the question *not an answer to the question asked*. In other words, whenever you posted something that answer any question vs that it answers the question.

Answer (score -13):

> What to do with answers in a different programming language than the one asked for?

First of all, is the question even a good question? Is it clear and precise in what it's asking? Much of the trouble identifying bad answer come from the problem of correctly interpreting the question. Remember, answers are supposed to answer the question asked, but if the question is ambiguous, how can you establish that?

If the question itself has problems, you would have problem evaluating the answer objectively and therefore reaching any form of common context that you can start discussions. On other hand, the language can be just pseudo-like code, in which case, the answer themselves aren't restricted either.

If the above doesn't exist, then these answers are not even a partial answer to the question and therefore fair play for moderation. Of course, if the question is complete and answerable without specifying any language at all, then the language of the answer doesn't matter.