# Is it okay to answer about software that is no longer maintained with different software?

Tags: discussion, answers, dead-tags

I am a big fan of web automation and scraping. Recently I started answering questions related to such in JavaScript, but I noticed people still use some popular, but non-maintained software which can easily be converted to working versions of different software/product.

Here is an example:

- [CasperJS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PhantomJS#CasperJS) and [PhantomJS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PhantomJS) are no longer maintained. Both of them have around 500~2000 active questions without any answer. Every day there are new questions about things that do not work. Some have thousands of views without any answer mostly because it doesn't work anymore.
- Nightmare and Puppeteer are two modern products. Most questions asked on the above mentioned tags can easily be replaced by these.

My question is:

- Can I answer those questions (about CasperJS and PhantomJS) with valid solutions with Puppeteer? Obviously I am going to mention how CasperJS is no longer maintained, but this exact problem can easily solved by Puppeteer instead, etc.
- Is it okay if I answer non-answered questions from 2011~2017? Most of them are solved anyway in later versions, but the questions are still online and gaining visitors.

I cannot not mention how much I suffered for that, finding a problem but never a solution anywhere, except an unanswered question on Stack Overflow. And I feel this question I am writing right now is also a duplicate, because I cannot be the only one person ever felt this way.

EDIT:

- I am not affiliated with any of the mentioned tech including CasperJS, PhantomJS, NightmareJS, Puppeteer.
- All of the mentioned software is in JavaScript. I could include some other software too, but included these because of the sheer popularity on GitHub and Stack Overflow. There is Selenium too, but has a bit different workflow. If new software with a more powerful and flexible API comes, I will probably use that instead.
- What I meant being easily converted, is most of them has **similar** syntax or workflow. Open website, click here, get title, get text, etc. I worked with all of the mentioned software and switched back and forth many times so it felt natural to me.
- However if it's too much to do so, I would not answer, because of the time it would take me to replicate the question.

Comment: What exactly does "*can easily be converted*" mean, are the two API-compatible and the only thing you need to change is the `import` statement (or `require()` call)?

Comment: What exactly is required to get Nightmare or Puppeteer running? I'm not savvy in JS, but if they're trivial to get working then that's a positive. If they're some complicated software to install, I'd be less inclined to want to do that. Are you affiliated with either of these, because it would also be worth mentioning that (if you are)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What to do with answers in a different programming language than the one asked for?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/375424/what-to-do-with-answers-in-a-different-programming-language-than-the-one-asked-f)

Comment: @stiemannkj1: I dispute the duplicate. This question has an extremely sharp focus that makes the general question not very relevant. If that were normally considered hard rule, I would consider this a plausible candidate for an exception.

Comment: Related: [xkcd 979](https://www.explainxkcd.com/wiki/index.php/979:_Wisdom_of_the_Ancients)

Comment: Thank you Laurel and Peter for the edits and Joshua for the dispute. I learned a lot from you.

Comment: Some folks still support mission critical hardware that runs on Windows 2000 or XP and nothing newer, so... yes. I imagine it's the same concept as still accepting questions about C89 or C99 rather than C11 or C18 (or substitute any old version of a programming language still in use)

Answer (score 84, accepted):

Yes, you can provide an answer that includes information about different libraries, frameworks, and languages.

Make sure that

- the answer actually answers the question as asked. "No, you can't" is a valid answer. Make sure to provide some explanation why it is not possible (like "Access to Foo is missing and library is unlikely to get updates" - see [Is "this is not possible" an acceptable answer?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261168/is-this-is-not-possible-an-acceptable-answer)).
- if you recommend another library, show how to do what is requested and not just link to the library, framework, or tool. Clarify how much effort it would likely take to switch (drop-in replacement, complete rewrite, etc.)
- if you are related to a new library in some way (owner, maintainer, seller, etc.), make sure to specify that.
- do not post the same/similar answers to multiple questions - vote to close as duplicates instead.

Warning: answers to old questions go to the "late answers" review queue. It means that such answers will likely get the attention of people who care about quality of posts. Promotion of any particular library in multiple answers likely cause concerns.

A sample template that I think would work:

> "The *Bar* feature can't be implemented with the *Baz* library. To implement *Bar* you need to access *Foo* properties which are not exposed in the library. Since the library is no longer maintained it is unlikely to become available.
>
> To support such cases, a group of people forked the library to the "*BazXR*" project (I'm contributing to it). This is almost a drop-in replacement for *Baz*, but it includes *Foo*. Below is sample code for how to do it in *BazXR*."

Comment: Thanks for such valuable response. One thing, if I answer to say hundreds or thousands questions with such answers, will I get a ban? I see new questions popping up every day but old ones doesn't have any "accepted answer", so I cannot even "mark them as duplicate" at this moment.

Comment: Note that "late answer" review queue are feed only by late answers *from new users*. Any other user answering an old question would not trigger it to the queue.

Comment: So answering "The *Baz* library is no longer maintained and the owner recommends switching to the *Foz* project. The *Foz* library is similar in syntax and *Bar* feature can be accessed as follows (having translated your code snippet to *Foz*:" is not okay?

Comment: @DavidMulder, yes provided you are truly trying to be helpful to the person that asked the question, rather than trying to promote Foz.

Comment: @Md.AbuTaher If there are indeed hundreds or thousands of such questions, perhaps a [Canonical Q/A](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/291992/what-is-a-canonical-question-answer-and-what-is-their-purpose) would be appropriate? I'm sure I couldn't say whether it would be or not in this specific case, having no knowledge of JS.

Comment: @Md.AbuTaher Also note that dupe targets don't need to have an accepted answer, an answer with positive score suffices.

Comment: @Md.AbuTaher if you are providing **unique targeted answers** to each of those thousands of questions you are fine. Note that providing good unique answer requires significant time (at very least to check if question is not duplicate) - I'd say 10 minutes is very optimistic lower bound (unless you are Jon Skeet :) )… so answering 1000 questions will take you a month of full time work... If you decided to go on such journey consider gaining gold tag in one of tags to speed up closing duplicates as soon as you find them during research of each answer. At very least flag as duplicates.

Comment: Thank you everyone for such kind and informative response. It helped me think clearly and plan forward.

Comment: Re ***"No, you can't" is a valid answer.***: Don't you mean ***"No, you can't" is not a valid answer.***?

Comment: @PeterMortensen I mean "is valid, but low quality" - https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261168/is-this-is-not-possible-an-acceptable-answer. I've reworded that sentence slightly which hopefully clarifies that.

Comment: @PeterMortensen "No" *is* a valid answer, according to Shog.

Comment: @Peter Mortensen: "No, you can't." being valid is *critical* in cases where no practical alternatives or workarounds exist.