# NAA flag declined on answer using completely different programming language

Tags: discussion, declined-flags, not-an-answer

Today I stumbled across [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74988011). The answer is explaining how to perform the task outlined in the question using JavaScript. However, the question is asking about a Python implementation. I left a comment on the answer pointing this out then flagged it as "not an answer".

Later on, I checked back on my flag and it was declined with the reason

> flags should not be used to indicate technical inaccuracies, or an altogether wrong answer

I personally don't understand how this could be seen as a "technical inaccuracy", and yes the answer is "altogether wrong"; not in the functional sense, but because it's using a completely different programming language than the question is asking about.

Looking at the description of the "not an answer" flag, it says

> This was posted as an answer, but it does not attempt to answer the question. It should possibly be an edit, a comment, another question, or deleted altogether.

I believe that this post "does not attempt to answer the question". Although functionally this answer (appears to) accomplish the task outlined in the question, **it is deliberately written in a completely different programming language**.

Is this an acceptable answer to the question being asked?

Comment: But, it is an answer to the question, not a good one, not one that is terribly relevant to the language of the question, but it still is an answer and does address some of the algorithmic issues mentioned in the question. Please see [What to do with answers in a different programming language than the one asked for?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/375424/) as well as [How should we handle answers in a programming language other than what the OP requested?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/271207/).

Comment: Funny thing is, I looked up those meta posts about 20-30 min ago when I ran across the very same question (thanks to the Queen bot), and if I hadn't, it would probably be me sending in the declined flag and then writing this question.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels Thank you, that pretty much answers my question. I have closed it as a duplicate. My takeaway from this is that although these *are* answers to the question (in a sense), they're not necessarily always *good* answers given the context.

Comment: You're welcome. But also, please check out the canonical meta Q&A about NAA Flag: [When to flag an answer as "not an answer"](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/265552/when-to-flag-an-answer-as-not-an-answer) which explains in greater detail why your flag was likely declined. The fruit metaphor is enlightening.