# Should an answer in the wrong programming language be flagged? Should incorrect answers be flagged?

Tags: discussion, support, answers, flags

If there's a question tagged with a specific coding language and someone answers it using a different language, should that answer be flagged?

To me, that's an completely incorrect answer.

Keeping that in mind, I recently had this comment on an (unrelated) flag:

> flags should not be used to indicate technical inaccuracies, or an altogether wrong answer

---

**To summarize:**

**Q1:** Should incorrect answers be flagged?

**Q2:** Is a "right answer in the wrong language" a incorrect answer?

I would've thought both cases should be flagged as "Not An Answer", since it neither contributes to a solution for the OP, nor is helpful to "future generations" Googling the same issue.

Comment: _someone answers it using a different language_  to clarify, you mean answer using a different programming language right? not a non english language.

Comment: Edit the title with programming language instead of just language.... So question is more clear....

Comment: As further illustration, see also [*Again a “not an answer” flag has been declined when the answer uses a completely unrelated language*](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/341596/2751851)

Comment: Thanks for pointing me to the dupe (don't know how I missed that)...  but so the consensus from that question is, yes, it is a wrong answer but I can't see clear direction on what to do with it?  Should it be flagged? [This](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/290049/8112776) answer leads me to believe that I should not "it's still an answer"...  How is something irrelevant to the question an answer to it?

Comment: You can flag it and add a comment below the answer to the effect that it is not trying to answer _this_ question as it is in a completely different programming language

Comment: No, don't ask 5 other users to solve a problem you can trivially solve yourself.  Or expect it, low odds that reviewers know the distinction between vba and vb.net.  I took care of it for you, but you need to downvote such a post yourself.

Answer (score 8):

> Should incorrect answers be flagged?

No. Factually incorrect answers should be downvoted. Leave a comment explaining why they're incorrect.

> Is a "right answer in the wrong language" a incorrect answer?

No. It is Not An Answer -- or, at least, not an answer to the question that was asked.

However, flag reviewers are likely to see the answer in isolation, and may reject a NAA flag on an answer that looks like it's an answer to something. Leaving a comment on the answer to explain what's wrong may help.

Comment: *may reject a NAA flag* ... that should say *with high probability reject a NAA flag* as it is an answer to **a** question.Which is (unfortunately?) all that is being looked at. An extra comment pointing out what is wrong with it might change the odds

Comment: So to the 2nd part you're saying "it's not answer but flagging it as not an answer is likely to to get rejected as an incorrect flag"...  I've been going through the other provided links and I'm more confused than before, there's no real consensus on this.  I only want to clarify so I can do my part in helping wade through some of the garbage so that the gold that SO has to offer is more readily accessible to all.

Comment: @ashleedawg  you know the [Your answer is in another castle](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/225370/your-answer-is-in-another-castle-when-is-an-answer-not-an-answer) post? And the [FAQ](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/185073/how-do-i-properly-use-the-not-an-answer-flag)? That gives as reason to not use NAA flag when *The answer makes an attempt to answer the question, even if it is wrong or inaccurate or you disagree with it*. Giving a Java answer to a C# question is an attempt.

Comment: @rene Hᴏᴡ is a post that's completely irrelevant to the question considered still an answer to the question? Are you saying that if you ask "What's 1+1?" and I answer "Blue", then that's a valid answer that deserves to remain here for all time (if it doesn't have enough traffic to get downvoted), taking up space, and confusing others, while possibly interfering with access to a REAL answer? Maybe a better comparison, what if I answer in a language that you don't understand? My answer could be 三|ثلا‎- Without an interpreter the answer does you zero good. (it's not "not very good", it's useless)

Comment: `Giving a Java answer to a C# question is an attempt`  Completely disagree.  It's not an answer any more than gibberish is an answer.  An attempt might be *attempting* to use the correct language even if the author wasn't very good at it.

Comment: @ashleedawg it is certainly worth down votes and delete votes but flagging is the wrong tool, at least up till today. We need a far bigger protest to have that handled differently. Switch to a custom flag to be sure of correct handling.

Comment: Alright, won't use NAA.... appreciate the feedback.

Comment: I tried to look up the definition of **`Attempt`**.  It said "`Attempt = an act of trying`"  So I looked up **`Try`** and it says "`Try = to make an attempt`"...  *\*sigh\*  I guess that answer is in another castle too*

Comment: @ashleedawg you're not the only one who gets confusing feedback on NAA. I think close to 100% of the regulars in SOCVR have had declined NAA flags and they are prolific flaggers. We've learned to live with it.

Comment: Should I then go through all my stuff and delete those that are not 100% complete, ie. pseudocode answers?

Answer (score -13):

### In my opinion

those incorrect answers, where you can see that the person was actually trying to help, should **NEVER** be flagged or downvoted **either**.

You can't blame someone for not being experienced enough to know the answer immediately, but he was just trying to help you.
Altough those answers that show no actual effort, or the person is showing no respect towards a beginner for example, should be downvoted/flagged.

**But** answering with a different programming language can be downvoted or flagged.
If you're learning Java for example, and nothing else, and you get an answer in in **C**, you can't do anything with it, if you know nothing about it.

Comment: Not be downvoted? the problem with that is without downvoting it wont tell other users that the given answer is _wrong_.That would do more harm than good to others searching for the problem

Comment: As I've noticed so far, on this page downvotes are mainly being used on really useless/rude answers/comments or incorrectly asked questions, not on wrong answers

Comment: People do downvote wrong answers and should. They are more careful downvoting because downvoting answers carries a penalty of -1 rep. Its to indicate quality

Comment: You're confusing voting on the content with my opinion about you as a person. I down voted this answer because I think it doesn't have advice that is valuable for future visitors. My down vote doesn't mean I blame you for posting this. On the contrary: I'm happy that some fresh blood share their ideas. So +1 for you as a person, although that is more a feature of facebook. Don't let voting get you personally.