# Where does one draw the line when it comes to answers in a specific tag self promoting an alternative tool?

Tags: discussion, self-promotion

I'm not going to point out who and what tags I'm referring to here to avoid any meta-effect, but you can probably figure it out based on my activity.

---

I'm not as active as I used to be on Stack Overflow but do follow closely some niche but active tags so I see it all due to the relatively low post count.

Over the past year, a particular user started answering questions under many unregistered accounts in this tag providing answers that utilized a tool he had developed that has similar goals but was a complete alternative, all without any disclosure. So every answer that he provided had the tone of

> "instead of using *that* tool, here's an alternative approach using *this* tool."

He answered many of the newest questions (at the time) and many older questions in this fashion.

At some point this year, it looked like all those answers were removed as they were most likely found to be "spam." But the answers continued to come in the same way. Eventually with a disclosure that he's the author after someone pointed out our self-promotion rules. Now the author has registered and still continues to answer in this way today in this tag.

I'm glad he's now disclosing the fact he's the author but it feels dirty to me that these answers are still like this. To me it's like answering [typescript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/typescript) questions with [coffeescript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/coffeescript) answers, or [powershell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/powershell) questions with [bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/bash) answers, or even [ios](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ios) questions with [android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android) answers. Sure, it may arrive at the same final answer, but it's not what was specifically asked for and the added self promotion makes it feel extra dirty.

**Is there a line to be drawn when answering questions that aren't directly answering the question in the requested tag? At what point is answering with "alternative" tools for a tag that doesn't ask for it, too much?**

Comment: [How to not be a spammer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/promotion) in the help center points out "Don't talk about your product / website / book / job too much," so the line is somewhere before "all the time" like this user seems to be doing.

Comment: Also, if the question is seeking help with a _specific_ tool **and** the answer _only_ talks about the "alternative" tool, I would [flag as NAA](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/366523/4934172) (or maybe a custom flag if that behavior is repetitive).

Comment: That’s not a recommended use of NAA or any other flag, @Ahmed. Answers that recommend alternative solutions are not only answers, but they’re often very useful answers. Moderators aren’t going to delete them. If you want us to have a chat with a user regarding excessive self-promotion, that’s a different issue, of course; a custom flag on one of the posts is an appropriate way to request that.

Comment: I see. Thanks for the clarification!

Comment: Link-only toolrecs are still NAA. If the answer suggests a different tool and shows how, then it's not NAA.

Comment: @Zoe I should clarify, they do show how the tool solves the problem so it's a perfectly valid answer, otherwise it would have been flagged.

Comment: "here's an alternative approach" out of the blue is a dead giveaway for spam/abusive self promotion

Comment: Sigh, ironically after putting this up and taking action on it, it looks like another person (of low rep) is pushing another tool as well on the same tag... now we have two different tools posting on the tag. smh

Comment: If you see a user answering questions about "how to do something in X" with "here's how you can do it in Y", please do not hesitate to downvote those answers for not answering the question, regardless of whether they are spammy feeling. You are exactly right in your concern about that feeling dirty.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

If there is disclosure, but it still feels spammy, mod flag. Mods see spam all the time and they're pretty good at noting when people are pushing the limits. Disclosure is **necessary** but that doesn't **excuse** being spammy either.

If you think there's a pattern, head over to [Charcoal](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/11540/charcoal-hq) and bring your examples. Charcoal has tools to track their posting a particular link and having a pattern definitely helps mods take action.

## Where do we draw the line?

Patterns. Post one link and we'll probably give you a mulligan (provided it's not "Buy this now!" junk). Post two, and we're dubious and probably watching, but maybe it's spam, maybe not. [Post the same URL four times to two different SE sites over the course of a day?](https://metasmoke.erwaysoftware.com/domains/36793) I don't think anyone would dispute that's spam.

Comment: By my count, 30 of 31 answers in this tag (out of 55 overall) mentions his tool, at least 5 with no disclosure. And this doesn't count the answers that isn't linked to the account. So when I see activity from this user, I am certain I know what kind of answer to expect.

Comment: Drop by Charcoal and ask. Bring some links and they can have their tools keep an eye out for you

Comment: There's no question in my mind on whether it's spammy or not, it certainly is. I'm just trying to figure out what the consensus is on this sort of behavior, do we like it or do we not. What Davy pointed out would definitely classify this as unwanted behavior I think.

Comment: Flagged an older post which has been marked helpful so I'm assuming some action was taken. Only time will tell whether the user in question takes this to heart.