# Is it acceptable to copy old Objective-C answers just to rewrite them in Swift?

Tags: discussion, answers

I recently saw a lot of very old questions tagged [Objective-C](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Objective-C) receiving new attention: new answers in [Swift](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Swift_%28Apple_programming_language%29) have been added. But these answers aren't actually *new*; they are just old answers being rewritten in Swift by another author.

I wouldn't mind new answers that showcase a new aspect, but simply picking the top answer (including explanatory text!) and rewriting the syntax to Swift doesn't do anything to the subject of the question.

Also these questions receiving new attention mostly are about system frameworks, which are very loosely coupled (if at all) to the language. So why copy another user's answer (content-wise) and post it again?

**Examples:** [Uno](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30603366/796103), [Dos](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31187076/796103), [Tres](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29218836/796103), [Cuatro](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1773257/796103)

There may have been better ones, but it feels like most I commented on have indeed been deleted in the meantime.

To distinguish this from [this previous question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285258/is-it-acceptable-to-post-answers-in-swift-on-ios-os-x-questions-marked-with-the): I am asking if it's OK to copy popular answers and rewrite them to another language. This is only syntactical sugar and has almost never anything to do with the question. The previous question linked above is about whether it is acceptable to answer a Swift question in Objective-C and vice versa.

Comment: Can you give some examples?

Comment: @Stijn Is there a way to see answers I commented on? I mostly leave a comment on those. I also added an example I stumbled upon today which made me make this post.

Comment: You can find your comments on your profile, see all actions -> comments. http://stackoverflow.com/users/796103/christian-schnorr?tab=activity&sort=comments

Comment: You should be able to find all your comments (excluding deleted ones) in the "all actions" tab on your profile. You can't search those, but you can manually scan through them and see if you can find examples this way.

Comment: In the dupe, take care: The OP didn't like the top-voted answer.

Comment: @Deduplicator This is an entirely different question. I am asking about unnecessarily making old questions active again while 'stealing' other user's content.

Comment: Well, the dupe answers the question whether an answer in "that new-fangled language" should be posted with a loud NO. Is it likely reposting an existing answer after translation to "that new-fangled language" is any more acceptable? You might have a case if you re-focus on those not tagged with the language at all.

Comment: @Kendra Done, thanks for the tip.

Comment: Maybe you like this answer better: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/271210

Comment: @Deduplicator I've gotta agree with Christian here, this is not a duplicate. There is a clear difference between asking if it is ok to reply in a different language than the one tagged and asking if it is ok to translate an existing answer to a different language.

Comment: @wmarbut: As I said, the latter, in his question, is just a very constrained version of the former. So if the former is bad, doesn't that adequately answer the latter? What more is there to say?

Comment: @Deduplicator the top answer in the former question calls out the confusion that people have between the objective c tag and the cocoa and cocoa touch tags. Assuming people use the tags correctly, this question remains relevant. "Can you duplicate an answer if you translate it without getting dinged for a duplicate?" is fundamentally different from "Can you answer in a different language?". I'll grant you that this question should perhaps be more broadly scoped to address all such situations where people translate existing answers (I've seen it in the Java / Groovy / C# world as well)

Comment: @wmarbut: The point you are not seeing is that the OP tied it to posting the translated answer *in that same question*. If he dropped the question where the translation is posted being language-tagged for a different language, **as I suggested**, it would no longer be a dupe.

Comment: @Deduplicator Yeah... I read you now. Agreed; That constraint does need to be dropped from the question.

Comment: Per the update, I've tweaked the wording of the title and the clarification, and I think this can stand on its own as a separate question. I've therefore reopened it. It's a topic that has come up a couple of times in flags, and I'd be interested in hearing the community's thoughts on it.

Comment: @BradLarson: Well, the question is still a duplicate. And it stays one as long as the question keeps asking about posting the new answer to the source question tagged with the source language and not the target language. Anyway, answered as if that part was dropped.

Comment: FWIW - I've found it useful to have some of the old Object-C answers revised to include Swift versions.  Even when searching on Swift, Object-C answers tend to be on top of results and often answer the same question... but I can see the argument from both sides ;-)

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/298596/dropdown-for-language-version

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Sure you can take a good answer and build upon it, like translating the code, translating the human language, applying to a different problem or whatever.

Still, don't post it to a question it doesn't fit (like [posting swift-code to objective-c questions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285258/is-it-acceptable-to-post-answers-in-swift-on-ios-os-x-questions-marked-with-the)), nor post it to any question where it doesn't add anything substantial.

Also remember all the content on the SE network is licensed under CC-BY-SA, so proper attribution is not only good manners (and we *really* frown on plagiarism) but actually a legal requirement.
A pointer from the source to the result might be useful as a comment or footnote in some circumstances.

Answer (score 10):

> Is it acceptable to copy old Objective-C answers just to rewrite them in Swift?

Is it acceptable to copy an answer **just** to rewrite it in another language? No, of course not. Imagine where we'd be if all our .NET-related Q&A was cluttered with exact copies of the C# answers rewritten in VB.NET or vice a versa. It'd be a mess.

But do you have any examples of that actual kind of behavior?

> it feels like most I commented on have indeed be deleted in the meantime

Perhaps those were the ones that actually should have been deleted?

I looked at the four examples you offered, and didn't see a single one that I thought was blatantly copied nor which failed to add *anything* to the discussion. In other words, I saw no evidence of this:

> simply picking the top answer (including explanatory text!) and rewriting the syntax to Swift

You also mention:

> Also these questions receiving new attention mostly are about system frameworks

If *all* that is different is the language, then I'd agree a translated post isn't useful. But even questions that are primarily "about system frameworks" can lend themselves to different approaches, depending on the language.

For example, your third example leads to an answer that uses extensions in Swift, a syntax unique to that language.

In your fourth example, it's not even a new answer. Someone has simply edited the previously-existing answer to include the Swift syntax (which IMHO is a good way to deal with the situation when all one really is doing is translating from one computer language to another).

So…I guess I'd say that the clear answer to the question you've asked is obviously "no, that's not acceptable". But I don't see that you're showing any examples of that actual kind of behavior. Perhaps you could track some down and replace the links in your post with more relevant ones? If not, perhaps you could at least be *specific* about why you believe each of your examples illustrates your question in a useful way.

Comment: I agree that the examples aren't the best, I should have researched better. But as I stated I feel like most of the ones I encountered and commented on have been deleted already. Thanks for your answer though!

Comment: _"have been deleted already"_ -- that seems to validate your opinion that _those_ particular answers should not have been written. So you seem to be on the right track...I guess my only suggestion is to give an answer the benefit of the doubt; if they appear to add anything new at all, and are not strictly copy/paste from another answer modulo the language translation, that's probably an acceptable answer.

Comment: Well, in some cases porting the answer from Objective-C to Swift is not trivial, and it's fair that the person who ported it gets rep. themselves, which is not the case when editing an answer of someone else...

Comment: Actually this is rather a pointer to missing functionality in StackOverflow. a dropdown for language (e.g. Apple's or Microsoft documentation, you can switch Obj-C/Swift or C#/C++/Js). AND VERSION, people always open a new question when new version of library is released, often the answer has only slightly different syntax. They all spread over the place + often people also forget to specify the version. It would really help with searchability.

Comment: I wrote a new question for this: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/298596/dropdown-for-language-version