# Should TypeScript answers to JavaScript questions, that make no attempt to explain themselves, be considered valid answers?

Tags: discussion, tags, not-an-answer

TypeScript (TS) and JavaScript are related languages, but they are not exactly the same.

It might be valid to answer a TypeScript question with pure JavaScript, but is the reverse ok?

It feels a little like the [age-old jQuery only answers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19478/the-many-memes-of-meta/19492#19492) to JavaScript questions, except not just an optional library, but a change in the language used.

Here is [an example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57839382/1075247) of a (almost) code only answer given in TypeScript. I can pretty much read it without knowing TypeScript, but I can't guarantee it would run if I stripped out all the 'TypeScript bits'.

Is this 'not an answer' ? Should it just be downvoted?

This is (in my opinion) not simply: *[How should we handle answers in a programming language other than what the OP requested?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271207/how-should-we-handle-answers-in-a-programming-language-other-than-what-the-op-re)*

The currently most upvoted answer there starts:

> It depends on the nature of the question.

The nature of the questions I'm trying to highlight is where no attempt is made to explain how the TypeScript answer relates to the JavaScript code.

The answer even just starts with 'This is the solution', and no mention of TypeScript.

As stated in a comment:

> There are two instances of TS specific code there it's (`axios as jest.Mocked<typeof axios>`) twice. The direct JS equivalent is literally the code `axios`.

This *obviously* takes some knowledge of TypeScript to understand, as least as far as I can see. For all I know, I need additional code if I want to translate it into working JavaScript code. Perhaps by specifying the type, [Jest](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jest_(JavaScript_framework)) handles or mocks [Axios](https://github.com/mzabriskie/axios) differently. Is the onus on me to know the ins-and-outs of TypeScript and how to translate it?

The answer by [VLAZ](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/3689450/vlaz) provides an interesting example:

> If a subject matter expert in graph theory can supply an optimal answer question tagged [javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/javascript) [graph-theory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/graph-theory) only in, say, [c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%23) then we should not discourage them.

I think that's even more of an orange, but at least if they make that clear, the answer has some *temporary* value. By no means do I think it should be the final or accepted answer, if every subsequent poster has to do that C# -> JavaScript translation. Ideally in this hypothetical case, the OP could/should self-answer with their translation. And suddenly there is not point in keeping the C# answer (it *could* be deleted, with no issues to the question). Heck, if possible that would have been better as a comment linking to the library elsewhere.

---

I wanted to get this reopened and self-answer to make it clear my intent, but it seemed better to just make a [new post, and self answer there](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/412921/1075247)

Comment: Valid in what way? They're certainly not "not an answer", and including types doesn't make them "very low quality",

Comment: "Not an answer" and downvoting aren't related. Answering a question in a completely different language that hasn't been asked about is could easily not  be useful to both the question asker and future readers, but that doesn't make it *not* an answer.

Comment: @KevinB I'm definitely not arguing they're 'very low quality', but if the asker isn't asking about typescript, is an answer using typescript actually answering the question?

Comment: This is hardly an entirely different language, in *many* cases typescript can simply have the type declarations removed and be valid javascript. You can choose to downvote if you think the answer isn't useful, but it being typescript alone shouldn't be the reason.

Comment: @Larnu if the question doesn't attempt to answer with JavaScript, I would definitely say it's not an answer...

Comment: That isn't "not an answer" by Stack Overflow terms, @Pureferret . Not an answer <> Not a *useful* answer. "Not an answer" on Stack Overflow means that the post is *literally* not an answer; it makes no attempt to answer a question, let alone the OP's. An answer that provides a solution in a different language is still an answer; just (likely) not a *useful* answer.

Comment: @Larnu The picture [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/225370/175002) is a good explainer. I'm saying JavaScript answers are Apples, TypeScript answers are oranged. They share a lot of similarities, but they aren't the same.

Comment: @ErikA that question starts with 'It depends on the nature of the question.' Well, I'm trying to provide the 'nature ' of the questions in my post

Comment: No, again, an answer in a different language is *still* an answer. End of Story. Usefulness does not equate, or even relate, to an answer being an answer or not.

Comment: @Pureferret Your question asks for a general "Is typescript to javascript valid", the answer there states you should handle it case-by-case which also applies here. There might be some questions that can't be properly answered using typescript because they specifically ask for javascript internals. If you wish to discuss your example case, it'd be different.

Comment: OK, I wrote my question without looking at your example. I didn't want to focus on it too much for the answer. Now that I did, I must say I'm *very* disappointed with the example you chose. There are two instances of TS specific code there it's `(axios as jest.Mocked<typeof axios>)` twice. The direct JS equivalent is literally the code `axios`. And you claim this is "not an answer" or "low quality" and in a comment you say you "can't see how this is easily applicable to their use case?". This is borderline claiming that we should only respond with directly copy-pasteable solutions.

Comment: The orange analogy is meant to refer to an answer that doesn't at all resemble an answer. Not **answers** to another question or a variation of the current question.

Comment: Honestly, I'd suggest the Orange is more that you asked how to achieve X in language Y, and got an answer about how the mechanics of a Steam Engine work. Not how to achieve X in Language Z (which can be implemented in Language Y).

Comment: The answerer in this case *clearly* intended to answer the question asked. This isn't an example of "Your question on javascript testing is great and all, but here's how to fly an airplane."

Comment: "*Is the onus on me to know how TypeScript works?*" counter-question to this one - if OP *does not understand the answer*, does that mean that it's not an answer? Followup question - since when is the OP *the only* user relevant? All the answers written are visible to everybody on the internet. In fact, the whole aim of SO is to *not* help a single person per answer. The OP of a question is *in the extreme minority* of people helped by an answer. One person vs potentially everybody else who visits the Q&A.

Comment: I'd also like to remind you that you are currently saying that an answer that uses *very slightly different language) is exactly the same thing as spam or a cat walking on the keyboard. These are the staples of NAA. Are you *sure* this is the argument you want to go with?

Comment: OK, I see I mixed it up. For some reason, I thought you were the OP of the example question. But I believe my point still stands. Just because *you* don't understand an answer, doesn't mean it's "not an answer". Imagine the poster didn't use TS but instead a function or syntax that you personally didn't know. The answer would then be in the same language, using the same libraries as the Q and everything. According to the argument you've put forward, that's still the equivalent of gibberish and should be deleted because you specifically did not understand it.

Comment: @VLAZ, perhaps my example does more  to obscure my concerns here, than it does to help me. And perhaps even *suggesting* it's not-an-answer was a step to far. I still believe these sorts of answers shouldn't be considered 'valid' but I'm not sure what that translates to on SO. It's less about understanding the answer than I made it out to be, so apologies for my lack of clarity there. The single salient point I'm trying to get at is, the answer makes no attempt to explain that they've answered in a different language/dialect *at all*.

Comment: As for spam and cats on keyboards, those are VLQ. The Not an answer close description reads "This was posted as an answer, but it does not attempt to answer the question. It should possibly be an edit, a comment, another question, or deleted altogether." A comment pointing to the typescript version, or answering with a small tweak to make it valid javascript is all I'm asking about.

Comment: I would be a little more sympathetic if, for example, it were a coffeescript answer to a typescript question. (it still wouldn't be NAA)

Comment: "*the answer makes no attempt to explain that they've answered in a different language/dialect at all*" if such a clarification *is* needed (arguable in many cases), then you can make an edit to the post. NAA means that *it should not been posted at all*. The goal of flagging NAA is for that answer be removed. It might be converted to a comment (e.g., if it was a clarification request like "Can you post the code for foo?"), to a different question (a user literally posting an answer instead of a new question), etc. Point is NAA = it never belonged in the answer box.

Comment: @VLAZ THAT is the sort of answer I was after. Apologies for me making it like pulling teeth. I didn't want to invalidate the answer by excising references to typescript, nor did I want to post a competing answer with the code changed to JavaScript ( and no way to test it actually worked ).

Comment: Dupe close voter here - why do you think that the dupe doesn't answer your question if we've already established that an answer in TypeScript *is* in fact an answer, and that by your own acknowledgement, that TypeScript and JavaScript are close (but not exactly the same)?   Were you also aware that you could simply [transpile TypeScript code into JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12678716/1079354), thus rendering what initial language the answer is provided in (because a common runtime exists) moderately moot?

Comment: Is there a jQuery to JavaScript transpiler?

Comment: @KevinB:  Yeah, but it's built-in to jQuery.

Comment: @Makoto it looked like that answer says "It depends" and I was trying to say "Ok, but if no attempt is made to explain it's a different language, does that matter?" I could have been clearer

Comment: As another SME here, TypeScript and JavaScript are not only *close*, but as one of the design goals of TS is to be a *superset* of JS - they are *extremely* related. We are not looking at a situation where the answered gave a Java answer to JS question, that would be problematic (but still does not make it NAA if it is an actual response to the question and not some unrelated gibberish), what we have here is a compile-to-JS language (remember CoffeeScript, anyone?) whose type system is completely non-intrusive. [1/2]

Comment: [2/2[ Granted, there is a small subset of TS code that will not run out-of-the-box even if you strip out types (think decorators, for example), but this is not the case here - all the code needs to be run is to strip out the types. Your concern about the answerer not explaining themselves is valid, though, and I see you already did the right thing by editing the information in, so this should be a win-win situation for everyone involved.

Comment: @KevinB I don't see why it wouldn't be possible?

Comment: @KevinB actually, there are quite a bunch of them - never tried using one, but still, that seems like a common task these days given that the library is becoming increasingly obsolete. It is sad to see, but I am happy that the language is becoming manageable to work with without a bunch of frameworks/libraries strapped on top (but I am sure you know all that given your main site activity :))

Comment: @OlegValter "this is not the case here" granted, after a few passes I hadn't missed something, and I'd have to be hoping that passing in the types doesn't change how Jest behaves for instance. Even if TypeScript were a strict superset (which, [I've heard argued it isn't](https://newbedev.com/is-typescript-really-a-superset-of-javascript) doesn't that mean there's *potentially* bits of TypeScript that aren't backwards compatible with JS that are outside of the 'base set' of functionality?

Comment: @Pureferret not sure how familiar you are with TS, but just for the sake of clarifying for others if you aren't (apologies if that sounds trivial) - the type system is *completely* stripped out and has 0 interactions with user code as the language itself (ECMAScript, I mean) is dynamically weakly typed. Specifying a type cannot, literally, change anything in how the program behaves - at max you can force the compiler to think buggy code is correct and vice versa (sometimes due to bugs in TS compiler itself), but that's the extent of it. There also are 0 features that not compatible [1/2]

Comment: @OlegValter I've got a passing familiarity, but I've never had to use it. [This is the sort of gotcha](https://fettblog.eu/react-types-for-children-are-broken/) I could see producing incorrect answers, even though the TypeScript is valid, and implies it should run correctly.

Comment: [2/2] with JS as far as I know (some of the exceptions are: decorators [which might or might not end up different once the proposal lands], enums (which are correctly transpiled to vanilla JS), and, to some extent, modules. I may be missing a couple of things, though. Speaking of being a superset - even this article argues that it is :) Every valid JS program is a valid TS program (unless you opt in for strict mode specifically, then yes, not so much). As for gotcha - yeah, this is what I referred to as "force the compiler to think buggy code is correct and vice versa" - that is possible.

Comment: Anyways, I do not think the point about "potential bits that aren't compatible" is invalid as a whole, and I think we should encourage answer authors to provide solutions as close to the original question as possible (including the language used) as for the numerous readers after the OP it is just an unnecessary mental strain and wasted time. I think the best way to approach this is to either comment and ask the person to provide a vanilla alternative or edit it in (especially given that we have the editing privileges). [1/2]

Comment: [2/2] That said, the author should likely be reminded that we consider links to the Playground a rule of thumb when answering questions with TypeScript - it is just good manners and, as @VLAZ rightfully mentioned, it has a live compiler that can convert the TS code into valid vanilla JS on the fly.

Comment: @OlegValter I agree about them making it clear. I [made a post about that](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/412921/1075247) just now.

Comment: @OlegValter There are no generics in ECMAScript (the big one missed :)).

Comment: @HereticMonkey oh, how could I, I guess interfaces count too then :)

Comment: *"The nature of the questions I'm trying to highlight is where no attempt is made to explain how the typescript answer relates to the javascript code."* - that's the nature of the answer, not the nature of the question.

Comment: 'Should it just be downvoted?" The universal answer here is to downvote all and everything at your leisure. If you feel it should be downvoted it should be for you.

Answer (score 2):

> Is this 'not an answer' ?

[image: Big flaming word "NO"]

(My apologies, but the Markdown formatting is a bit limited. I am unable to use flaming letters here, so I had to use this image. Thanks to [Larnu](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/2029983/larnu) for supplying it.)

The "Not an answer" flag should be used for things that *should not be put in the answer box*. That does not mean "technically inaccurate". It does not even mean "I do not like this answer". It means: spam, separate questions, remarks like "I have this problem too", [link-only answers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/225370/your-answer-is-in-another-castle-when-is-an-answer-not-an-answer), pure gibberish, etc. Things that are *not* answers because they do not even attempt answering the question as required by the site. Anything that attempts to answer the question is, not surprisingly, an answer.

For more information see the FAQ entry: [When to flag an answer as "not an answer"](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/265552/when-to-flag-an-answer-as-not-an-answer)

> Should it just be downvoted?

*Maybe* [image: Big flaming asterisk] [image: Two big flaming asterisks]

(again due to limitations of Markdown, I could not apply maximum emphasis on the asterisks, so I had to use images.)

* Just because an answer is in another language, does not mean that it is automatically not useful. People can answer questions that are tagged with one language in pseudocode to outline an algorithm to be applied without writing in a specific language. Or they can write C, or Python, or any other language they are more familiar with *if it is clear what they mean*.

There is no requirement for the answer to be in the same language. Yes, that is the expectation but we are primarily looking for *useful* answers. Just because somebody wrote an answer in another language does not automatically make it not useful. Indeed, it might be *very* useful - we *want* experts to answer. If a subject matter expert in graph theory can supply an optimal answer question tagged [javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/javascript) [graph-theory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/graph-theory) only in, say, C# then we should not discourage them. Algorithms are easy to translate. That knowledge is far more valuable than knowing how to write a particular language.

** TypeScript in particular is not even something hard to work into a JavaScript answer. At the very least, anybody can copy/paste the TypeScript code into the [online compiler](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/) and get the equivalent JavaScript code. It is also very easy to directly translate TypeScript to JavaScript. So, I do not see how a TypeScript answer is not useful. It often reads even easier than JavaScript. Yes, it does rely on a little bit of knowledge of TypeScript (to read the types correctly) but good code should be self-descriptive anyway. Therefore, I would expect good TypeScript code to not be a problem for people with JavaScript background to read. After all, TypeScript should be compatible with JavaScript anyway.

Comment: Do either of these meet your burning text needs? :) [1](https://r78.cooltext.com/rendered/cooltext397286130244323.gif) [2](https://r76.cooltext.com/rendered/cooltext397286164291234.gif)

Comment: @Larnu thank you, I used number 2. I think it better conveys the message I am striving for.

Comment: @Larnu on a mostly unrelated note, I seem to have found a bug on that cooltext website. Apparently trying to generate an image of a flaming asterisk symbol doesn't work. Unless there are *other* symbols present. I can't seem to get one with just an asterisk or two.

Comment: It does seem to "not" like it, @VLAZ (I only found the site by Googling "Flaming Text Generator"). Though I did manage to generate one by entering "Maybe \\* \\*\\*" first, and then removing the `\ ` characters

Comment: I've updated my question to more clearly state my issue

Comment: @Larnu no, I mean it works if there is *any* other symbols. Well, except spaces. `x*` works but `*` does not. I ended up using a...workaround. I made a composite image: the basis is `*` (which renders nothing) and for a composite, I chose the burning logo again and typed in `x *` which generated a flaming X and a flaming asterisk. The composite image you can move, so I adjusted it so the `x` is outside the image and resized to just get the `*`. Repeated the same with `x **` for two asterisks.

Comment: You inspired me to write this: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/comments/878287?noredirect=1

Comment: Re *"The "Not an answer" flag"*: Can you address link-only answers as well?

Comment: @PeterMortensen included them with a link for more information.