# Should answers make it explicitly clear when they answer with a different programming language?

Tags: discussion, answers

Answers to questions, that use a language not specified in the body or the tags are [potentially valid](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271207/how-should-we-handle-answers-in-a-programming-language-other-than-what-the-op-re) (quoting from the answer: "It depends on the nature of the question.")

But should answers make it explicit when they use a different language (even if highly related)?

I'm mainly trying to find out to what extent it's sufficient to just edit a question rather than leave a comment and *potentially* downvote if it looks like the answerer has left an unhelpful answer.

Comment: There really are only exceptional times when this is tolerated.  For instance, a question about an algorithm (which doesn't bind itself to a specific architecture-type problem) or JavaScript-based languages.  Every other time it's usually a red flag.

Comment: I'm wondering just what exactly you expect such answers to clarify. It's usually very obvious that language A is not language B, and when it's not the difference is usually just not relevant. Surely when posting a code block that does not work in language X, saying "this is not language X" isn't helpful?

Comment: If it isn't already clear that it's a different language just from the way that it is, is the fact that it's different important? Take the example javascript question answered with "typescript." the first snippet would compile and run in javascript without a single complaint. the second would throw a syntax error with a line number. Inconvenient? Sure! but i'd hope someone writing unit tests like that would be able to figure out a syntax error. If they can't, they can always downvote, or request clarification.

Comment: @kevinb "If they can't, they can always downvote, or request clarification" that's the kind of thing I'm trying to capture here

Comment: @makato did you see my examples in the CW answer? Otherwise the gist of what you said would be good as it's own answer, especially if you expand on 'red flag'

Comment: @MisterMiyagi I'm thinking things like Python 2 Vs Python 3, or flavours of C code where small snippets look similar.

Answer (score -8):

### Answer should, wherever possible, make it clear they're answering in another language.

(this answer is intended to be updated with helpful examples, *when answering*, please add them as you see fit. This is ***not*** meant to be used to justify votes/flags/bad edits against posts)

At a minimum, you should be open about your language choice, and if possible justify it.

#### Language choice is a preference

If the two languages are more or less the same (i.e JavaScript and TypeScript), it's probably best to just remove or not add the 'extra bits' (like types) into your answer. Here is [an example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57973722/1075247).

For instance, if you have in your answer:

```
  (global as any).Blob.mockReturnValueOnce('mocked blob');
```

And the 'extra bits' (e.g. `as any`) aren't needed for the answer<sup>*</sup>, it's trivial to not include them in your answer. If you must, then preface your code explaining the choice you've made and how to convert it, or if there're not many examples, then leave a comment inline. Beware of [gotchas](https://fettblog.eu/react-types-for-children-are-broken/) when libraries don't live up to the expectations of your chosen language.

#### Language is shared by a framework

> questions about Selenium, which exists for Java, JavaScript, Python, C#, Ruby, and other languages. The API is regular enough that it is possible for someone using Ruby to understand an answer written in Python.

While these are ok, they should still explain how to make use of the answer, and their value to the Stack Overflow depends on how closely related they are. Here is an OK Ruby [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15574466/1075247), and an OK Java [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7290968/1075247) but here is an example of a much better, more explicit answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8575709/1075247).

#### Language is *not quite* a subset (i.e., not just preference)

Examples include using [CoffeeScript to answer JavaScript](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CoffeeScript#Syntax), or [C to answer C++](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compatibility_of_C_and_C%2B%2B) (or vice versa). You probably need to be much more careful, justify your choice, and potentially reconsider answering or at least which language you're using to answer.

These two code blocks from the linked Wikipedia page are comparable:

```
const mass = 72
const height = 1.78
const BMI = mass / height ** 2
if (18.5 <= BMI && BMI < 25) { alert('You are healthy!') }
```

```
mass = 72
height = 1.78
BMI = mass / height**2
alert 'You are healthy!' if 18.5 <= BMI < 25
```

But others on that Wikipedia page are not too compatible. Similar cases can be found for C and C++, although these seem to be [few](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69842462/1075247) and far between.

#### Language is unrelated, but provides an analogy

The answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62140663/1075247), gives an example that shows what the OP wants is *possible*, even if the language the answerer used is not the same, but they still make it clear which language it's in. There may be better examples.

---

<sub>* if you're quoting existing code, that is also valid for 'needing' to include them.</sub>

Comment: I've made this a community wiki to collect helpful examples.